# How to retrieve a module's path?

Tags: python, module, inotify

I want to detect whether module has changed. Now, using inotify is simple, you just need to know the directory you want to get notifications from.

How do I retrieve a module's path in python?

Comment: Check out modulefinder: http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html

Comment: If you are still looking on this site, please update the correct answer to [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154601/131120). It is way cleaner than the proposed solution and it works also in cases where `__file__` is not set.

Comment: @erikb85: it is not only cleaner; `inspect`-based solution also works for `execfile()` case when `__file__` produces wrong name silently.

Comment: related: [How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3718657/4279)

Comment: `import pathlib, module; pathlib.Path(module.__file__).resolve().parent` This is platformindependent

Comment: module.__path__[0]

Comment: I am using Jupter notebook and i have another notebook file say GetData and there is a class ABC. I have imported this class ABC in a different notebook `from GetData import ABC` but when i use inspect.getfile(GetData) or print(GetData.__file__) i get error name GetData is not defined or attrinute __file__ not found. Problem is modified the class ABC whose function is called from notebook which imports it and see the output is still same as old file. But if i make same changes in GetData and run from GetData notebook it is reflected.

Comment: Some answers list several caveats for `__file__` that do not seem to apply to Python 3.10 when I try it. `__file__` is an absolute path for module `a` when I run `python3 a.py` or add a shebang and run `./a`. I'm not sure if the caveats still apply in some cases and I'm not sure in which version of Python this different behavior of `__file__` was introduced.

Answer (score 1300, accepted):

```
import a_module
print(a_module.__file__)
```

Will actually give you the path to the .pyc file that was loaded, at least on Mac OS X. So I guess you can do:

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath(a_module.__file__)
```

You can also try:

```
path = os.path.dirname(a_module.__file__)
```

To get the module's directory.

Comment: this answers how to get the path of the module you import, but not of the module/script you are in (for the script you're running, `__file__` is not a full path, it is relative). For the file I'm in I had to import another module from the same directory and do as shown here. Does anyone know a more convenient way?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but does self.__file__ provide different results than \_\_file__?

Comment: @hbdgaf pretty sure there is no such thing as a built-in `self.__file__`

Comment: @BenBryant @hbdgaf `os.path.dirname(__file__)` works fine for me and returns the abs path of the module's directory.

Comment: The `__DoubleUnderlinedNames__` are meant to be called by Python operators or built-in functions, so I guess it should be Python to call the `__file__` attribute instead of directly by programmer. SummerBreeze's answer follow this convention better I think.

Comment: I tried doing this and get the traceback:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: @DorianDore I was messing with modules a little and got to a solution `path = module.__path__.__dict__["_path"][0]`, but I'm not sure if it's portable or if it doesn't differ between python versions either. It's working for me, unlike this answer which gives me the same error and `inspect` answer raises `TypeError: <module 'module' (namespace)> is a built-in module`...

Comment: this technique is not working for all the modules, becz there are many modules without __file__ variable. just like builtins modules does not contain __file__ variable

Comment: @Dorian Dore, I was refactoring someones code where I had to get the path to a folder within the package's structure. My code errored out until I realized that the folder who's path I was trying to find did not have an \_\_init\_\_.py inside of it. Without an \_\_init\_\_.py, you can import the folder, but you will not be able to use the \_\_file\_\_. Hope this helps someone

Comment: For your own packages, you can also use this structure: ```from .my_folder import __file__ as path_to_folder_init```

Comment: This also fails if you are unable to import an installed module.

Answer (score 385):

There is `inspect` module in python.

### [Official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html)

> The inspect module provides several useful functions to help get
>   information about live objects such as modules, classes, methods,
>   functions, tracebacks, frame objects, and code objects. For example,
>   it can help you examine the contents of a class, retrieve the source
>   code of a method, extract and format the argument list for a function,
>   or get all the information you need to display a detailed traceback.

Example:

```
>>> import os
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(os)
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> inspect.getfile(inspect)
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.pyc'
>>> os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect))
'/usr/lib64/python2.7'
```

Comment: You can use `inspect` to get the name of the current file too; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/50905/320036

Comment: I googled this question many times and *this* is the most reasonable answer I have ever seen! Please update the information about `inspect.currentframe()`

Comment: the `inspect.getfile()` approach doesn't work with the module `_io`, but works with the module `io`.

Comment: Note that `inspect.getfile` can throw a `TypeError` for built-in modules.

Answer (score 82):

As the other answers have said, the best way to do this is with `__file__` (demonstrated again below). However, there is an important caveat, which is that `__file__` does NOT exist if you are running the module on its own  (i.e. as `__main__`).

For example, say you have two files (both of which are on your PYTHONPATH):

```
#/path1/foo.py
import bar
print(bar.__file__)
```

and

```
#/path2/bar.py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
print(__file__)
```

Running foo.py will give the output:

```
/path1        # "import bar" causes the line "print(os.getcwd())" to run
/path2/bar.py # then "print(__file__)" runs
/path2/bar.py # then the import statement finishes and "print(bar.__file__)" runs
```

HOWEVER if you try to run bar.py on its own, you will get:

```
/path2                              # "print(os.getcwd())" still works fine
Traceback (most recent call last):  # but __file__ doesn't exist if bar.py is running as main
  File "/path2/bar.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(__file__)
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Hope this helps. This caveat cost me a lot of time and confusion while testing the other solutions presented.

Comment: In this case, you can use sys.argv[0] in place of __file__.

Comment: Is that a version-specific caveat? In 2.6 and 2.7, I successfully rely on __file__, which works file when __name__=='__main__'.  The only failure case I've seen is with "python -c 'print __file__'".  I will add that sometimes __file__ can be '<stdin>', which happens when IDEs like emacs execute the current buffer.

Comment: Note that leading-and-trailing "__" characters put a word in bold, so keep that in mind when reading the previous comments :-P

Comment: @PaulDuBois You can surround it w/ back tics: \``__file__`\` becomes `__file__`

Comment: `then "print __file__" runs`, hey, what has happened to `print os.getcwd()` in bar.py when imported from foo.py with `import bar`?

Comment: It's there. "`/path1        # "import bar" causes the line "print os.getcwd()" to run`"

Comment: How do you get the `NameError`? @Paul Du Bois: I've tried Python 2.3-3.4 and `__file__` is defined however I run Python file: `python a.py`, `python -ma`, `./a.py`.

Answer (score 75):

I will try tackling a few variations on this question as well:

1. finding the path of the called script
2. finding the path of the currently executing script
3. finding the directory of the called script

(Some of these questions have been asked on SO, but have been closed as duplicates and redirected here.)

### Caveats of Using `__file__`

For a module that you have imported:

```
import something
something.__file__
```

will return the **absolute** path of the module.  However, given the folowing script foo.py:

```
#foo.py
print '__file__', __file__
```

Calling it with 'python foo.py' Will return simply 'foo.py'.  If you add a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
#foo.py
print '__file__', __file__
```

and call it using ./foo.py, it will return './foo.py'.  Calling it from a different directory, (eg put foo.py in directory bar), then calling either

```
python bar/foo.py
```

or adding a shebang and executing the file directly:

```
bar/foo.py
```

will return 'bar/foo.py' (the **relative** path).

### Finding the directory

Now going from there to get the directory, `os.path.dirname(__file__)` can also be tricky.  At least on my system, it returns an empty string if you call it from the same directory as the file.  ex.

```
# foo.py
import os
print '__file__ is:', __file__
print 'os.path.dirname(__file__) is:', os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

will output:

```
__file__ is: foo.py
os.path.dirname(__file__) is:
```

In other words, it returns an empty string, so this does not seem reliable if you want to use it for the current **file** (as opposed to the **file** of an imported module).  To get around this, you can wrap it in a call to abspath:

```
# foo.py
import os
print 'os.path.abspath(__file__) is:', os.path.abspath(__file__)
print 'os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) is:', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

which outputs something like:

```
os.path.abspath(__file__) is: /home/user/bar/foo.py
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) is: /home/user/bar
```

Note that abspath() does NOT resolve symlinks.  If you want to do this, use realpath() instead.  For example, making a symlink file_import_testing_link pointing to file_import_testing.py, with the following content:

```
import os
print 'abspath(__file__)',os.path.abspath(__file__)
print 'realpath(__file__)',os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

executing will print absolute paths something like:

```
abspath(__file__) /home/user/file_test_link
realpath(__file__) /home/user/file_test.py
```

file_import_testing_link -> file_import_testing.py

### Using inspect

@SummerBreeze mentions using the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module.

This seems to work well, and is quite concise, for imported modules:

```
import os
import inspect
print 'inspect.getfile(os) is:', inspect.getfile(os)
```

obediently returns the absolute path.  For finding the path of the currently executing script:

```
inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
```

(thanks  @jbochi)

```
inspect.getabsfile(inspect.currentframe())
```

gives the absolute path of currently executing script (thanks @Sadman_Sakib).

Comment: inspect.getfile(os) is the same as os.__file__
from the code:

def getfile(object):
    """Work out which source or compiled file an object was defined in."""
    if ismodule(object):
        if hasattr(object, '__file__'):
            return object.__file__

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you for this exhaustive answer.

Comment: Adding here that `inspect.getabsfile(inspect.currentframe())` gives the absolute path of currently executing script.

Answer (score 52):

I don't get why no one is talking about this, but to me the simplest solution is using **imp.find_module("modulename")** (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html?highlight=import#module-imp)):

```
import imp
imp.find_module("os")
```

It gives a tuple with the path in second position:

```
(<open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py', mode 'U' at 0x7f44528d7540>,
'/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py',
('.py', 'U', 1))
```

The advantage of this method over the "inspect" one is that you don't need to import the module to make it work, and you can use a string in input. Useful when checking modules called in another script for example.

**EDIT**:

In python3, `importlib` module should do:

Doc of `importlib.util.find_spec`:

> Return the spec for the specified module.
>
> First, sys.modules is checked to see if the module was already imported. If so, then sys.modules[name].**spec** is returned. If that happens to be
>   set to None, then ValueError is raised. If the module is not in
>   sys.modules, then sys.meta_path is searched for a suitable spec with the
>   value of 'path' given to the finders. None is returned if no spec could
>   be found.
>
> If the name is for submodule (contains a dot), the parent module is
>   automatically imported.
>
> The name and package arguments work the same as importlib.import_module().
>   In other words, relative module names (with leading dots) work.

Comment: imp is NOT depreciated in python 2 (current version 2.7.13). imp is depreciated in python 3 since 3.4. importlib shall be used in python 3 instead. I like this solution, because it even works when the actual import will fail (e.g. because 64bit module for a 32bit engine)

Comment: And REALLY nice when trying to find the path of 64 bit sqlite3 and import fails. Perfect.

Comment: `importlib.machinery.PathFinder().find_module("os").get_filename()` Shortest alternative to `imp.find_module` I've found in Python3+. If anyone is looking for the usage of `importlib.util.find_spec`.

Comment: This method works without importing the actual module, which is great as I am using this to figure out which version of a module is being imported from a shared computer.

Comment: **DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of `importlib`**.. and *"AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'find_module"*

Answer (score 22):

This was trivial.

Each module has a `__file__` variable that shows its relative path from where you are right now.

Therefore, getting a directory for the module to notify it is simple as:

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Comment: Almost but not quite right -- __file__ is *not* "relative to where you're at right now"; when it's relative (which it will be only when there are relative paths in sys.path), it's relative to *where you were when the module was loaded*.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.9 `__file__` is [always an absolute path](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes).

Answer (score 17):

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dir_path = os.path.dirname(path)
```

Comment: doesn't work on my Linux python 2.6 since `__file__` is just dir/test.py, abspath involves the cwd to complete the pathname which is not the desired result, but if you import a module then `m.__file__` gives the desired result.

Answer (score 16):

```
import module
print module.__path__
```

> Packages support one more special attribute, `__path__`. This is
>   initialized to be a list containing the name of the directory holding
>   the package’s `__init__.py` before the code in that file is executed.
>   This variable can be modified; doing so affects future searches for
>   modules and subpackages contained in the package.
>
> While this feature is not often needed, it can be used to extend the
>   set of modules found in a package.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to retrieve the module path **without loading** it:

```
import importlib.util

print(importlib.util.find_spec("requests").origin)
```

Example output:

```
/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py
```

Comment: An underrated answer. Just what I was looking for. Caveat is the module is not imported. When you're programmatically running `pytest` for coverage, if you import the module you're testing before invoking pytest then all the imports, class/func definitions etc would be marked as not covered because it was already imported.

Answer (score 11):

### Command Line Utility

You can tweak it to a command line utility,

```
python-which <package name>
```

[image]

---

Create `/usr/local/bin/python-which`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import importlib
import os
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
if len(args) > 0:
    module = importlib.import_module(args[0])
    print os.path.dirname(module.__file__)
```

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/python-which
```

Answer (score 9):

you can just import your module
then hit its name and you'll get its full path

```
>>> import os
>>> os
<module 'os' from 'C:\\Users\\Hassan Ashraf\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\os.py'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

When you import a module, yo have access to plenty of information. Check out `dir(a_module)`. As for the path, there is a dunder for that: `a_module.__path__`. You can also just print the module itself.

```py
>>> import a_module
>>> print(dir(a_module))
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
>>> print(a_module.__path__)
['/.../.../a_module']
>>> print(a_module)
<module 'a_module' from '/.../.../a_module/__init__.py'>
```

Answer (score 6):

So I spent a fair amount of time trying to do this with py2exe
The problem was to get the base folder of the script whether it was being run as a python script or as a py2exe executable. Also to have it work whether it was being run from the current folder, another folder or (this was the hardest) from the system's path.

Eventually I used this approach, using sys.frozen as an indicator of running in py2exe:

```
import os,sys
if hasattr(sys,'frozen'): # only when running in py2exe this exists
    base = sys.prefix
else: # otherwise this is a regular python script
    base = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to retrieve the package's root path from any of its modules, the following works (tested on Python 3.6):

```
from . import __path__ as ROOT_PATH
print(ROOT_PATH)
```

The main `__init__.py` path can also be referenced by using `__file__` instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: This code is intended to go in python packages. Make sure all folders have an `__init__.py` file. Googling that error shows other potential causes

Answer (score 6):

Er...

```
>>> import logging
>>> print(logging)
<module 'logging' from 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\logging\\__init__.py'>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to know absolute path from your script you can use [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path().absolute())
print(Path().resolve('.'))
print(Path().cwd())
```

[cwd() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd)

> Return a new path object representing the current directory (as returned by os.getcwd())

[resolve() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve)

> Make the path absolute, resolving any symlinks. A new path object is returned:

Comment: This will fail because it will only return the working directory, not the modules path

Answer (score 5):

If you installed it using pip, "pip show" works great ('Location')

$ pip show detectron2

```
Name: detectron2
Version: 0.1
Summary: Detectron2 is FAIR next-generation research platform for object detection and segmentation.
Home-page: https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2
Author: FAIR
Author-email: None
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: yacs, tabulate, tqdm, pydot, tensorboard, Pillow, termcolor, future, cloudpickle, matplotlib, fvcore
```

#### Update:

$ python -m pip show mymodule

(author: wisbucky)

Comment: Calling `$ pip show mymodule` is not reliable. You need to do `$ python -m pip show mymodule`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path/68976819#68976819

Answer (score 3):

If the only caveat of using `__file__` is when current, relative directory is blank (ie, when running as a script from the same directory where the script is), then a trivial solution is:

```py
import os.path
mydir = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
full  = os.path.abspath(mydir)
print __file__, mydir, full
```

And the result:

```
$ python teste.py 
teste.py . /home/user/work/teste
```

The trick is in `or '.'` after the `dirname()` call. It sets the dir as `.`, which means *current directory* and is a valid directory for any path-related function.

Thus, using `abspath()` is not truly needed. But if you use it anyway, the trick is not needed: `abspath()` accepts blank paths and properly interprets it as the current directory.

Comment: Better swap the order and just use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` because then you don't have to worry about relative paths at all. One less opportunity for bugs.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to contribute with one common scenario (in Python 3) and explore a few approaches to it.

The built-in function [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) accepts either relative or absolute path as its first argument. The relative path is treated as *relative to the current working directory* though so it is recommended to pass the absolute path to the file.

Simply said, if you run a script file with the following code, it is **not** guaranteed that the `example.txt` file will be created in the same directory where the script file is located:

```
with open('example.txt', 'w'):
    pass
```

To fix this code we need to get the path to the script and make it absolute. To ensure the path to be absolute we simply use the [os.path.realpath()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) function. To get the path to the script there are several common functions that return various path results:

- `os.getcwd()`
- `os.path.realpath('example.txt')`
- `sys.argv[0]`
- `__file__`

Both functions [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) and [os.path.realpath()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) return path results based on the *current working directory*. Generally not what we want. The first element of the [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) list is the *path of the root script* (the script you run) regardless of whether you call the list in the root script itself or in any of its modules. It might come handy in some situations. The [__file__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) variable contains path of the module from which it has been called.

---

The following code correctly creates a file `example.txt` in the same directory where the script is located:

```
filedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filepath = os.path.join(filedir, 'example.txt')

with open(filepath, 'w'):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

A modern (Python >= 3.7) solution to this problem is `importlib.resources.files()`

```
from importlib import resources
resources.files(package_name)
# => WindowsPath("C:\Path\to\your\package\")
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'importlib.resources' has no attribute 'files'

Comment: So Sorry! Fixed it. Copy pasted the wrong version of my code the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this dynamically in a "program" try this code:
My point is, you may not know the exact name of the module to "hardcode" it.
It may be selected from a list or may not be currently running to use __file__.

(I know, it will not work in Python 3)

```
global modpath
modname = 'os' #This can be any module name on the fly
#Create a file called "modname.py"
f=open("modname.py","w")
f.write("import "+modname+"\n")
f.write("modpath = "+modname+"\n")
f.close()
#Call the file with execfile()
execfile('modname.py')
print modpath
<module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>
```

I tried to get rid of the "global" issue but found cases where it did not work
I think "execfile()" can be emulated in Python 3
Since this is in a program, it can easily be put in a method or module for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

From within modules of a python package I had to refer to a file that resided in the same directory as package. Ex.

```
some_dir/
  maincli.py
  top_package/
    __init__.py
    level_one_a/
      __init__.py
      my_lib_a.py
      level_two/
        __init__.py
        hello_world.py
    level_one_b/
      __init__.py
      my_lib_b.py
```

So in above I had to call maincli.py from my_lib_a.py module knowing that top_package and maincli.py are in the same directory. Here's how I get the path to maincli.py:

```
import sys
import os
import imp


class ConfigurationException(Exception):
    pass


# inside of my_lib_a.py
def get_maincli_path():
    maincli_path = os.path.abspath(imp.find_module('maincli')[1])
    # top_package = __package__.split('.')[0]
    # mod = sys.modules.get(top_package)
    # modfile = mod.__file__
    # pkg_in_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(modfile)))
    # maincli_path = os.path.join(pkg_in_dir, 'maincli.py')

    if not os.path.exists(maincli_path):
        err_msg = 'This script expects that "maincli.py" be installed to the '\
        'same directory: "{0}"'.format(maincli_path)
        raise ConfigurationException(err_msg)

    return maincli_path
```

Based on posting by PlasmaBinturong I modified the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick bash script in case it's useful to anyone.  I just want to be able to set an environment variable so that I can `pushd` to the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
module=${1:?"I need a module name"}

python << EOI
import $module
import os
print os.path.dirname($module.__file__)
EOI
```

Shell example:

```
[root@sri-4625-0004 ~]# export LXML=$(get_python_path.sh lxml)
[root@sri-4625-0004 ~]# echo $LXML
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/lxml
[root@sri-4625-0004 ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used `pip`, then you can call `pip show`, but you must call it using the specific version of `python` that you are using. For example, these could all give different results:

```sh
$ python -m pip show numpy
$ python2.7 -m pip show numpy
$ python3 -m pip show numpy

Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Don't simply run `$ pip show numpy`, because there is no guarantee that it will be the same `pip` that different `python` versions are calling.

Answer (score 1):

If your import is a site-package (e.g. `pandas`) I recommend this to get its directory (does not work if import is a module, like e.g. `pathlib`):

```py
from importlib import resources  # part of core Python
import pandas as pd

package_dir = resources.path(package=pd, resource="").__enter__()
```

In general [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) can be considered when a task is about accessing paths/resources of a site package.

Answer (score 1):

Here im printing **cProfile** package path:-

```
import cProfile
import os
path = os.path.abspath(cProfile.__file__)
print(path)
```