# Why does os.getcwd() return System32 path on Windows (sublime text 2 plugin)?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

So I was working on a ST2 plugin, and needed to get the current path, so I did:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

I was surprised that it returned C:\Windows\System32 .. Instead I had to do something like:

```
import sublime
dir = sublime.packages_path()
package_path = os.path.join(dir, 'NAME_OF_YOUR_PACKAGE')
```

I'm looking for an explanation as to why the **System32** path is returned.

Comment: Apparently `System32` was the working directory of your python process. What did you expect `getcwd()` to return?

Comment: @Robᵩ Wouldn't **C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2** make more sense?

Comment: @potatoes No, it does not. That's where the program installed. Why should it be the working directory? A sensible alternative could have been the home of the user(something like `C:/Documents and Settings/<username>` maybe... I always forgot the windows hierarchy).

Comment: @Bakuriu Ahhh, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getcwd() will return Python's current working directory.  Not the directory where your script is running from.

Comment: If you are looking for the current executing script's directory, then take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/python-how-to-find-scripts-directory

Also, you might be interested in the inspect module.