# How do I find directory of the Python running script from inside the script?

Tags: python, directory

How do I find the directory of the running Python script from inside Python [3.3]?
I have tried what was suggested at: [How can I find script's directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/python-how-to-find-scripts-directory) , but I get "Invalid syntax" and directed to "os" (And I did import os).

The closest I have got to the answer is: `sys.argv[0]`, but that still includes the file name, so I cannot use it. Is there any other way?

The part where it says `rundir = sys.argv[0]` is where the suggested code will go:

```
import os, sys

rundir = sys.argv[0]
print("Running from" + rundir)
```

Comment: Can you post your exact code and the exact error you get? The answer you linked sounds like it should work for you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To get the directory that contains the module you are running:

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Or if you want the directory from which the script was invoked:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file.

Depending on how the script is called, this may be a relative path from `os.getcwd()`, so `os.path.realpath(__file__)` will convert this to an absolute path (or do nothing is the `__file__` is already an absolute path).  `os.path.dirname()` will then return the full directory by stripping off the filename.

Comment: You can get a `Path` object via `Path(__file__).resolve().parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

`__file__` gets the name of the file you are in.  The `dirname` function gets the directory that the file is in.

The syntax error probably had to do with the print statement.  In python 3.x

```
print "hi"
```

is invalid.  Print is now a function.

```
print("hi")
```

works.  You need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import os,sys
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])))
```