# create a file outside the directory in python

Tags: python, file

I want to create a file outside the current working directory in python. Here's my directory structure.

```
|--myproject
|   |-- gui
|   |   |-- modules
|   |   |   |-- energy
|   |   |   |   |-- configuration
|   |   |   |   |   |-- working_file.py
|   |-- service
|   |   |-- constants
|   |   |   |-- global_variables.json
```

I'm current working in `/myproject/gui/energy/configuration/working_file.py` and I want to create a file under `/myproject/service/constants` named `global_variables.json`

I tried

```
with open("../../../../../service/constants/global_variables.json", 'w') as file_handler:
        content = json.load(file_handler)
```

Comment: Where do you write to the file handle?

Comment: What? I didnt get you.

Comment: 1) check current working directory 2) where do you want to create it 3) check where it was actually created 4) profit (fix the path)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath-  Well, the problem is the file isnt getting created at all, that's why I posted. Hence would have followed your steps on my own,

Comment: so you supplied an invalid path. surely you can come up with a valid one (for test), right?

Comment: isnt the path valid? It certainly is.

Comment: You say you want to create a file but you are actually reading a file, which you have opened in `w` (write mode). So what do you want to do?

Comment: Why are you opening a file in write mode and then trying to read from it?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Can you please provide your suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870603/django-content-type-table-auth-permission

Answer (score 6):

Relative paths are resolved from the current *working directory* and not from the directory where the script is located. If the file you're trying to create needs to be on a specific directory, use an *absolute* path (e.g. `/absolute/path/to/myproject/service/constants/global_variables.json`).

If you *can't* know this absolute path, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Python doesn't interpret `../`, it will look for a directory named ".." in the cwd.</strike>

You either have to hardcode the path:

```
with open("/path/to/myproject/service/constants/global_variables.json", 'w') as file_handler:
    content = json.load(file_handler)
```

Or find the full path to the current executing script:

- [Python: How to find script's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/python-how-to-find-scripts-directory)
- [In Python, how do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executin)

EDIT: I was wrong, python does interpret "..", what's happening here is that's is start is the cwd not your script.

```
$ echo 'Hello world' > text_file.txt
$ mkdir test/
$ cd test
$ python
[...]
>>> open('../text_file.txt').read()
'Hello world\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path is correct?

Assuming that the current path is:
  ../myproject/gui/modules/energy/configuration

The path that you mention is:

```
"..(a)/..(b)/..(c)/..(d)/..(e)/service/constants/global_variables.json"  

(a) = energy/
(b) = modules/
(c) = gui/
(d) = myproject/
(e) = ../
```

your services directory is I think in the myproject directory not in the one before it. Not sure if that is your question ... Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is find current file path and script directory path from that path, like this

```
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

And then you can add or join the place where you want to create file respective to this path

```
jsonfilepath = "../../../../../service/constants/global_variables.json"

reljsonfilepath = os.path.join(dir, jsonfilepath)

f = open (reljsonfilepath, 'w')
```

Please check as this is untested code.

Answer (score 0):

For the given below Project Structure:

```
.
`-- myproject
    |-- gui
    |   `-- energy
    |       `-- configuration
    |           `-- test.py
    `-- services
        `-- constants
            `-- out.txt


import os

## Finding absolute path of the current module
drive, tcase_dir = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.abspath(__file__))

## It's good if we always traverse from the project root directory
## rather than the relative path
## So finding the Project's root directory
paths = tcase_dir.split(os.sep)[:-4]
base_dir = os.path.join(drive,os.sep,*paths)


## Known Sub-Directories
SERVICES_DIR = r'services'
CONSTANTS_DIR = r'constants'

## absolute path to the ../myproject/service/constants/ directory
constants_abs_path = os.path.join(base_dir, SERVICES_DIR, CONSTANTS_DIR)

with open(os.path.join(constants_abs_path, r'out.txt'), 'r') as fp:
    ## Do the file Operations here ##
```