# Reading multiple lines from an external text file in Python

Tags: python, text-files, readline

This program works fine when I use the code

```
for character in infile.readline():
```

Problem is the readline only reads one line of text. When I add "s" to readline command

```
for character in infile.readlines():
```

I end up getting for 0's my output.

```
os.chdir(r'M:\Project\Count')

def main():
    infile = open("module3.txt","r")
    uppercasecount = 0
    lowercasecount = 0
    digitcount = 0
    spacecount = 0
    for character in infile.readlines():
        if character.isupper() == True:
            uppercasecount += 1
        if character.islower() == True:
            lowercasecount += 1
        if character.isdigit() == True:
            digitcount += 1
        if character.isspace() == True:
            spacecount += 1

    print ("Total count is %d Upper case, %d Lower case, %d Digit(s) and %d spaces." %(uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount, spacecount))

main()
```

Also if anyone could give me advice, can I take that directory and make it a default location so i can take this and use it on someone else's machine.

Comment: `f.readlines()` read in all the lines.  For the directory, you could pass as a parameter to your script.  And `if something == True:` should be `if something:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check the type of caracters contained in the file, I wouldn't use readlines but a regular [read](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

```
STEP_BYTES = 1024

def main():
    infile = open("module3.txt","r")
    uppercasecount = 0
    lowercasecount = 0
    digitcount = 0
    spacecount = 0
    data = infile.read(STEP_BYTES)
    while data:
        for character in data:
            if character.isupper() == True:
                uppercasecount += 1
            if character.islower() == True:
                lowercasecount += 1
            if character.isdigit() == True:
                digitcount += 1
            if character.isspace() == True:
                spacecount += 1
        data = infile.read(STEP_BYTES)

    print ("Total count is %d Upper case, %d Lower case, %d Digit(s) and %d spaces." %(uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount, spacecount))

main()
```

If you really need to use `readlines`, keep in mind that that method will read all the lines of the file and put them in memory (not so good with very large files) in a list of lines.

For instance, assuming that your `module3.txt` file contains:

```
this Is a TEST
and this is another line
```

Using `readlines()` will return:

```
['this Is a TEST\n', 'and this is another line']
```

With that in mind, you can walk the file contents using a double `for` loop:

```
def main():
    infile = open("module3.txt","r")
    uppercasecount = 0
    lowercasecount = 0
    digitcount = 0
    spacecount = 0
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for character in line:
            if character.isupper() == True:
                uppercasecount += 1
            if character.islower() == True:
                lowercasecount += 1
            if character.isdigit() == True:
                digitcount += 1
            if character.isspace() == True:
                spacecount += 1
    print ("Total count is %d Upper case, %d Lower case, %d Digit(s) and %d spaces." %(uppercasecount, lowercasecount, digitcount, spacecount))

main()
```

As for the directory thing, if your code and your text file (`module3.txt`) are going to be shipped in the same directory, you don't need to do the `chdir`. By default, the working directory of the script is the directory where the script is.

Let's say you ship it in a directory like:

```
  |-> Count
     |-> script.py
     |-> module3.txt
```

You can just use relative paths to open `module3.txt` from within `script.py`: the line `open("module3.txt", "r")` will go look for a file called `module3.txt` withing the directory where the script is running (meaning, `Count\` ). You don't need the call to `os.chdir`. If you still want to make sure, you could `chdir` to the directory where the script is located (take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/python-how-to-find-scripts-directory)):

Knowing that, change your hardcoded `chdir` line ( `os.chdir(r'M:\Project\Count')` on top of your file) to:

```
print "Changing current directory to %s" % os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two-form `iter` to read them an arbitrary number of bytes at a time, and `itertools.chain` to consider them as one long input. Instead of keeping track of several variables, you can use the `str` methods as keys to a `collections.Counter`, eg:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counts = Counter()
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    chars = chain.from_iterable(iter(lambda: fin.read(4096), ''))
    for ch in chars:
        for fn in (str.isupper, str.islower, str.isdigit, str.isspace):
            counts[fn] += fn(ch)

#Counter({<method 'islower' of 'str' objects>: 39, <method 'isspace' of 'str' objects>: 10, <method 'isdigit' of 'str' objects>: 0, <method 'isupper' of 'str' objects>: 0})
```

Then `counts[str.lower]` will give you `39` for instance...