# Change working directory from VBA to a UNC

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to change Excel's working directory using a UNC name?..

This: [Changing working directory from Excel vba shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276705/changing-working-directory-from-excel-vba-shell) explains how to use ChDir / ChDrive.
However, there's no such thing as "Drive"† for a UNC link.

The following naïve code does not change CurDir:

```
ChDir "\\testserver\longunc\directory"
Debug.Print CurDir()
C:\Documents\ZZZ
```

And the following obviously fails:

```
ChDrive "\\testserver\longunc\directory"
Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument
```

† *"Drive"?.. Changing "drive" in 2019?.. How daft is that! Why does this concept even still exist, Microsoft?..*

Answer (score 2):

You can the [SetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) function.

Import to VBA:

```
Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
```