# How to determine location where python code is called if it is stored in different location

Tags: python

Let's say I'm calling a python file from this directory:

```
 $ pwd
 $ my_dir1/path1/
 $ python mydir2/path2/my_code.py
```

Note that `my_code.py` is stored at another directory.
What I want to do is in `my_code.py` determine where it is called.
Namely I want it to display `my_dir1/path1/`.

What code should I put in `my_code.py`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find script's directory with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory-with-python)

Comment: @minitoto: No it's different. It's returning where the code is 'stored' not 'called'

Comment: read you question, it's what you asked

Comment: The title of your question seems to be different from what you're asking in the question itself. Here, `my_dir1/path1` is the current working directory.

Comment: @Riaz: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `__file__` global variable.

```
> cat mydir2/path2/my_code.py
print __file__
> python mydir2/path2/my_code.py
mydir2/path2/my_code.py
```