# python script - counting lines of code in the script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, lines-of-code

I am running a python script on my raspberry pi and I was just wondering if there is any command that I can use that counts how many lines are in my script.

Regards

Comment: From within the script?

Comment: Which editor are you using?  Most editors have the feature to display line numbers, but often it is not switched-on by default.

Comment: This is a shell access on the pi and I am editing it using nano .. wc -l command worked for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `wc` command:

`wc -l yourScript.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can [get the path of the script being run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9350788/1391325) and then read the file, counting all lines which are neither empty nor start with a `#` symbol or either `'''` or `"""` (all of which denote comments):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
This script prints out all significant lines of code contained within 
itself.
'''

import os
import re

SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER = "#"
MULTILINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER_PATTERN = re.compile("['\"]{3}")

class SignficantLineParser(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.in_comment_section = False

def parse(self, line):
    line = line.strip()
    if self.in_comment_section:
        if line.startswith(SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER):
            return False
        else:
            if MULTILINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER_PATTERN.match(line):
                # Exiting multi-line comment
                self.in_comment_section = False             
    elif line:
        if line.startswith(SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER):
            return False
        else:
            if MULTILINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER_PATTERN.match(line):
                # Entering multi-line comment
                self.in_comment_section = True
                return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False


script_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
with open(script_path, 'r') as inf:
    parser = SignficantLineParser()
    significant_lines = 0
    for line in inf:
        if parser.parse(line):
            significant_lines += 1
            print("Significant line: " + line, end="")

print("\n\nSignificant line count: %d" % significant_lines)
```

This prints out:

```
Significant line: import os
Significant line: import re
Significant line: SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER = "#"
Significant line: MULTILINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER_PATTERN = re.compile("['\"]{3}")
Significant line: class SignficantLineParser(object):
Significant line:   def __init__(self):
Significant line:       self.in_comment_section = False
Significant line:   def parse(self, line):
Significant line:       line = line.strip()
Significant line:       if self.in_comment_section:
Significant line:           if line.startswith(SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER):
Significant line:               return False
Significant line:           else:
Significant line:               if MULTILINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER_PATTERN.match(line):
Significant line:                   self.in_comment_section = False             
Significant line:       elif line:
Significant line:           if line.startswith(SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER):
Significant line:               return False
Significant line:           else:
Significant line:               if MULTILINE_COMMENT_DELIMITER_PATTERN.match(line):
Significant line:                   self.in_comment_section = True
Significant line:                   return False
Significant line:               else:
Significant line:                   return True
Significant line:       else:
Significant line:           return False
Significant line: script_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
Significant line: with open(script_path, 'r') as inf:
Significant line:   parser = SignficantLineParser()
Significant line:   significant_lines = 0
Significant line:   for line in inf:
Significant line:           if parser.parse(line):
Significant line:               significant_lines += 1
Significant line:               print("Significant line: " + line, end="")
Significant line: print("\n\nSignificant line count: %d" % significant_lines)

Significant line count: 35
```

Comment: oh ! thanks to you .. Though what I wanted was simpler; just one command line. However I have to admit this gives me an idea that supports my script .. Thanks to you :)