# Python can't find path with Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, filepath

I have a rather unusual problem. I wrote a python script which needs API keys. Since I don't want them floating around on the internet I created a seperate .json with the keys and added it to .gitignore. So far so good.

I wrote the program with VSCode and there I could execute it no problem. But when I try to use my program with the normal PowerShell it simply won't work. I get this error message when I run it on the external PS: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './master-folder/key.json'`

I use a virtualenv, for the packages but that shouldn't affect anything (of course I activated it in PS). Here's the part of the code once again:

```
keys_fp = './master-folder/key.json'

keys = load(open(keys_fp, 'r'))
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── programs
│   └── program.py
└── key.json
```

Comment: Add an `os.getcwd()` call in your script and see what it tells you.

Comment: @ritlew it outputs nothing, kinda strange

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @ritlew sorry, had to comment out the whole code, now it says, its in `E:\Git\master-folder\programs` exactly where it should be I suppose

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use relative paths.  This doesn't appear to be a powershell problem at all. `keys_fp = os.getcwd() + '\..\key.json'`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 well it kinda is, because PS is inconsistent. VSCode uses PS as the internal shell, but when I try it outside with the same command it doesn't work.So you say I should use an absolute path to the file?

Comment: @nerdlab as a best practice? always.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 ok, it works now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, your working directory is

```
E:\Git\master-folder\programs\
```

and inside your script, you're referencing

```
./master-folder/key.json
```

which resolves to

```
E:\Git\master-folder\programs\master-folder\key.json
```

but that doesn't exist.  If you adjust your script to use the proper path, it should resolve your problem:

```
keys_fp = f'{os.getcwd()}\\..\\key.json'
```

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory-with-python), you can access the script's root with the following:

```
import os
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
keys_fp = f'{root}\\..\\key.json'
```