# Getting a Python Modules Dierctory from Inside Itself

Tags: python, module, path, directory

I have a Python module and I'd like to get that modules directory from inside itself. I want to do this because I have some files that I'd like to reference relative to the module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get a reference to the module inside itself.

```
mod = sys.__modules__[__name__]
```

Then you can use `__file__` to get to the module file.

```
mod.__file__
```

Its directory is a `dirname` of that.

Comment: The `__file__` attribute was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As you are inside the module all you need is this:

```
import os
path_to_this_module = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

However, if the module in question is actually your programs entry point, then `__file__` will only be the name of the file and you'll need to expand the path:

```
import os
path_to_this_module = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this  is what you are looking for:

```
import <module>
import os
print os.path.dirname(<module>.__file__)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `pkg_resources` for this, the [`resource`* family](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#distribution-methods) of functions do just about everything you need without having to muck about with the filesystem.

```
import pkg_resources
data = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "some_file")
```