# discover path of python module

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path)

Suppose I have code in 3 python files. x.py, y.py, z.py.

x calls y and y calls z.  In the code in z.py, I want to know what directory x.py is in.

Is there a function that will tell me this?

EDIT
forget z.py.  I just want y.py to print out the path of x.py.
EDIT

Note that the system has 30 different files all named x.py located in different directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code in `z.py` has indirectly imported `x.py`, it will be in `sys.modules`. So try:

```
module = sys.modules.get('x')
if module is not None:
    print module.__file__
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Somethings not working.  Module is None.  I edited my question.  I don't care about z.py anymore.  I just want y.py to print out the path of x.py.

Comment: @user584583. it will only work if `x` has already been imported before `y` is. if x.py is the main script and imports `y`, it won't work, because `x` will not be imported.

Answer (score 2):

Import `x` and evaluate `x.__file__`.

Comment: Note that the system has 30 different files all named x.py located in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance those imports may lead to chain imports. So, in some functions namespace import **main** module.

```
def where_is_x():
    import __main__
    print __main__.__file__
```