# get path from a module name

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im sure there is a simple way to get a modules path from the modulename, right? I.e. I want to retrieve /path/to/module from path.to.module preferably in python 2.7.

I dont intend to import the module and I have the modulename as a string.

Comment: Does this post/answer address your question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question, I dont intend to import the module. The post thus doesnt help and I have read it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.modules['path.to.module'].__file__`

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import collections
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['collections'].__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc'
>>>
```

Comment: Why use `sys.modules` if you are importing the module into the current namespace anyway?  Simply `collections` will do.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, you are right, but he has module path, not reference to the module object

Comment: Well, the OP meanwhile clarified that the module shouldn't be imported at all, so neither `sys.modules['collections'].__file__` nor `collections.__file__` will help.

Comment: @Sven: You're correct, I've removed my other comments -- but the OP accepted this answer...

Answer (score 10):

This is fairly easy after importing a module:

```
import os
print os.__file__
```

prints

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
```

on my machine.

To do this *before* importing a module, you can use `imp.find_module()`:

```
imp.find_module("os")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
path = path.to.module.__file__
```