# How to find the path of a module by module name in python on fedora

Tags: python, path, web.py

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path)

I am working on python,i installed web.py framework to develop small web applications
and installed successfully.
When i tried to import the from python interpreter as below

```
>>> import web
>>>
```

Actually i want to know the installation path of the framework or a module where it is installed so i tried

```
>>> import sys
>>> import sys.path
```

ofcourse it is showing the path of many modules installed in `sitepackages`, but whether we can find the path of the module if we know the module name in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in sys.modules. For example:

```
>> import django
>> import sys
>> sys.modules['django']
<module 'django' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

Then: if you are constantly running into trouble with module paths [ and need to take control of that ], I'd suggest that you take a look at virtualenv ( http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html ). It is the de-facto solution to the "module import hell" problem in the Python world.

Comment: The question marked as a possible duplicate above [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path ] has other approaches, some of which may be better. I like the "inspect" approach