# Detect definition path of a decorated function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Are there any ways to obtain a path of a file corresponding to a function object which is passed to a decorator function?

Finally I need a directory of the file.

```
def mydec(arg):
    def dec_inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # how to detect a path where func is defined?
        return wrapper
     return dec_inner
```

Comment: Do you mean the name of the module (`func.__module__`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No. I mean something similar to result of os.path.realpath().

Comment: Well once you have the module name, you can find the module path - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/247770/3001761 - `sys.modules[func.__module__].__file__`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the name of the module a function comes from using the `__module__` attribute:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> choice.__module__
'random'
```

You can get the module from its name via the [`sys.modules` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
>>> sys.modules['random']
<module 'random' from 'C:\Python27\lib\random.pyc'>
```

And the file path itself from the `module` attribute `__file__`. Putting all of that together:

```
>>> sys.modules[choice.__module__].__file__
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\random.pyc'
```