# How to find the path of a module in python

Tags: python

```
from aqt import mw
```

It is from an anki(a program make in python) add-on source code, where can I find the `mw` file? I found folder /usr/share/anki/aqt, but I didn't find `mw` folder or `mw.py` file, where else could it be? Or is there method to display its path?

Comment: `mw` could be an entity (eg an object, function or constant) defined in the `aqt` module. Is there an `aqt.py` or `aqt.pyc` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to identify the type of  `mw`, do `type(mw)` in your python console. It might be something defined in the `__init__.py` file of the `aqt`dir. If 'mw' is a module, then you can try `mv.__file__`.

Answer (score 1):

Start python interpreter with `-v` flag, for every import its path will be printed like a comment
Here an example with a funny module:

```
user@host ~/$ python -v
###
#a bunch of bultin imports
###
>>> import sexmachine
import sexmachine # directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sexmachine
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sexmachine/__init__.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sexmachine/__init__.py
import sexmachine # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sexmachine/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/248862/276451).

```
from aqt import mw
print mw.__file__
```

Edit: wtf? "Trivial answer converted to comment"?