# How to reference static file in Django app's view

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I know there have been many questions here on accessing static files in a Django project, but I could not find a satisfactory answer to a problem I am dealing with. So, here's my project structure:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── app
    ├── admin.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
    │   └── app
    │       └── file.txt
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

As per [Django 1.7 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) I have stored the static file *file.txt* in *app/static/app* folder. Now, how do I reference this file in a view? Lets just say I need to read the contents of this file for every call defined in app/views.py.

As usual, I have default setting of *STATIC_URL = '/static/'* in project/settings.py

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can import the `static` template tag into your view and use it as such:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static

url = static('app/file.jpg')
```

Comment: I need to access the static file in a view, not in a template tag. Above can't work in a view.

Comment: Is there a way of not hardcoding the name of the app?

Comment: You will have have to hardcode the name of the app, as it defines the directory it is stored in.

Comment: @SiddharthGupta: Is there not a way to get the app's name inside its view?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni You could probably do something fancy with `inspect` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path/12154601#12154601)), but IMO you're better off defining it explicitly. You could use a global in your module to define the app name and juse use that wherever you call `static`. Or, you could define a wrapper around `static`.

Comment: @SiddharthGupta: I get {'appname': None} as a result of call to that method.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Have a look at my answer and I think that will help.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by defining STATIC_ROOT in your settings. Then before running your project you can run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And the static files then can be accessed using:-

```
file = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'app/a.txt'))
```

This is basically the way, it is supposed to be done in a production environment, as static files are hosted separately from the django html views.

To load the name of app dynamically in project/urls.py

```
url(r'^', include('app.urls', app_name="app")),
```

and then in views:-

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
def appname(request):
    return resolve(request.path).app_name
```