# Using files in a package in a thread-safe way

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm making a python package that uses data files. I add data files in my setup.py like that:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='foo',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'foo': ['test.txt'],
    },
)
```

And the files are arranged like this:

```
/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        foo_module.py
        test.txt
    setup.py
```

But the code like this

```
open('test.txt')
```

in foo_module.py stops working when I call it from outside the package. I believe that happens because I change my current working directory, and there is no file test.txt in my cwd. I suppose I can solve this problem by changing my current directory in the package code like this:

```
curdir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
open('test.txt')
os.chdir(curdir)
```

But I'm not sure if this code is safe to use in multiprocessing processes beacuse it modifies `cwd`. I could use locks, but I don't want the processes to wait for each other only because they change `cwd`.

Is there a conventional, thread-safe way to access files added to the package in setup.py?

Comment: why don't you just open the file with the absolute path instead?

Comment: @eugecm I'll need to know the absolute path, which may be different because of os, python version, whether I'm using virtualenv and maybe something else.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path on how to get the absolute path of the module, doesn't matter where it is, you can always use `__file__` to find out where it's installed

Comment: @eugecm I see now. Not very bright of me, I already used `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get abs path to the module, could have figured it out, sorry.