# OS X Uninstall a distutils installed project

Tags: python, macos

I'm on El Capitan and I want to install numpy with pip. However I get the following error:

```
Detected a distutils installed project ('numpy') which we cannot uninstall. The metadata provided by distutils does not contain a list of files which have been installed, so pip does not know which files to uninstall.
```

The existing numpy version seems to be 1.10.4 and the one I try to install is 1.9.2, but I need it. Is there a way to uninstall this version with distutils? Or at least any way to tell pip that there is numpy installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there is no metadata about the installed files, I found the easiest way to be removing the files manually. Simply retrieve the directory of the module (I referred to this: [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path)), and delete the folder, as well as the accompanying .egg-info file. Then install your desired numpy version without the --update flag.

Comment: i simply used the module name and a regex to find the egg file and deleted both

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your item was installed with anaconda. For your numpy, Try:

```
conda uninstall numpy
```

I got the same error, and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to this is to create a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and install the version of NumPy that you want in that.

```
$ virtualenv pandas
New python executable in /Users/gaius/pandas/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ . pandas/bin/activate
(pandas) Dawn-Treader:~ gaius$ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
```

If you look at the one you already have:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

There's no guarantee that that won't be touched by a future OSX patch or upgrade and your changes overwritten, if you do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

It works when I had trouble with uninstall tensorflow of lower version. It should be that if a package is installed by conda, the way to uninstall it through