# pip3 psutil cannot install newer version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, distutils, psutil

I am trying to install odoo 11.0 but when installing requirements it shows me this:

> Cannot uninstall 'psutil'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall

How can I uninstall it or upgrade to other version?

I already remove the files of **psutil** but it still sh.ows the same message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X Uninstall a distutils installed project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857242/os-x-uninstall-a-distutils-installed-project)