# Import Pandas from a path

Tags: python, pandas, path, libraries, libs

I created a program to filter out rows of data that have empty cells, however, the people that will be using this program do not have any libraries installed, they only have Python 2.7. Is there a way to import Pandas via a path from a network drive? I looked up similar questions, but I can't even seem to find the path on my computer to Pandas (I installed all libraries with Anaconda). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used sys

```
import sys
sys.path.append(/mynetwork/path_to_pandas)
import pandas
```

Comment: How would I find the path to the Pandas on my computer? I have looked in common places that I found in other questions/answers, but I installed Pandas with Anaconda.

Comment: That is a different question - which has an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path