# How to print import paths with [dot]?

Tags: python, import

I am reading through some code and was trying to look where the files where imported from. I read through this thread [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path) and so I tried

```
print _init_paths.__file__
```

which worked. But when I tried

```
print fast_rcnn.train.__file__
```

I get an error saying NameError: name 'fast_rcnn' is not defined. Note that the following 3 lines below have no errors i.e. the files have been successfully imported.

```
import _init_paths
from fast_rcnn.train import get_training_roidb, train_net
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg, cfg_from_file, cfg_from
```

Comment: Well you haven't actually imported the name `fast_rcnn` - try `import fast_rcnn; print fast_rcnn.__file__`. Alternatively, if you don't want to import that module, try `sys.modules['fast_rcnn'].__file__` (for which you will also need to `import sys`).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that fast_rcnn is a folder and that train is the python file I am importing. I was wondering if I could get the location of train.py which is in the folder fast_rcnn.

Comment: If you know where that file is, then what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Im just trying to learn new things. Plus it took me awhile to find out where the file was located so it would be nice if I could print a path to it directly for future use.

Comment: Well in general, you need to have the actual name of the thing you want to find - `from fast_rcnn import train; print train.file`, or `import fast_rcnn; print fast_rcnn.train.__file__`.

Comment: Ah okay so the only solution is to import the folder then print the location of the file within that folder. Thanks !