# Where are include and libs when using a Python virtual environment?

Tags: python, cmake, virtualenv, pybind11

I use a Python virtual environment. Basically, it works fine, but I run into problems when compiling some Python bindings, namely with libIGL and pybind11.

CMake has the following Python-related variables:

```
 PYTHON_EXECUTABLE                /users/me/libs/pyvenv/bin/python                           
 PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR               /usr/include/python2.7                                          
 PYTHON_LIBRARY                   /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so
```

It seems that it can detect the executable **which is a python3.5** of the previously-activated virtual environment properly, but it finds some wrong 2.7 paths for include and library.

So I'd like to just set those paths manually to my virtual environment. I browsed around in the directory structure of the virtual environment, and I think I found the includes in `/users/me/libs/pyvenv/include/python3.5m`. But I can't find the `libpython*`, there's no `*.so` file at all in my virtual environment. So which library should I use in that case?

Comment: Obviously, you should use the correct library! I believe the library you would be looking for should be the same as above, replacing `python2.7` with `python3.5`. By the way, it would be nice to have a reproducible example. And could you explain a bit more about "CMake has the following Python-related variables"? (Are these environment variables, set in a script...etc)

Comment: @Adonis: As far as I understand, the question is about existing projects (libIGL and pybind11) which use [find_package(PythonLibs)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindPythonLibs.html) for detect Python libraries. So the code is unlikely needed here.

Comment: Tsyvarev, yes, it would be nice if CMake would find the files automatically. But the question can be understood even more basic, just as: "Where do I find "libpython" in a virtual environment."

Comment: I am not expert with virtual environment in python, but I **guess** the python library  **doesn't depend** from the environment. Environment determines site packages as python scripts or libraries, but basic python library remains the same. So, probably you need to search the library file in system location, like `/usr/lib64/`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: While your proposed method solved the problem, I still find it very unsatisfying. The purpose of a virtual environment is to provide access to a Python installation without caring about the underlying system. So directly accessing the library in system-specific paths kind of violates this principle. Just my 2 cents ;-)

Comment: You may treat python library as part of "underlying system". So placing it outside of environment directory violates nothing.

Comment: Yes, but that means that a Python virtual environment does not provide/interface to a full Python installation. Unless there's good reason, it seems very arbitrary or even bug-ish to not provide a link/alias to the library, while includes and binaries are provided.

Comment: @Michael Hello, what did you end up doing for "PYTHON_LIBRARY"? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict python libs to match version of found interpreter in cmake:

```
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}" REQUIRED )
```

Or use [FindPython](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindPython.html) if cmake>=3.12 is availble

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path), you could run python from within your `virtualenv` and run

```py
import pybind11
print(pybind11.__file__)
# '/home/me/.pyenv/versions/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybind11/__init__.py'
```