# How to get installed python package folder path?

Tags: python, python-c-api

How to get installed python package folder path in Python C API?

Suppose I want to open a file `data.txt` from the Python C-API `module.pyd` that resides as follows:

```
package
   |--module.pyd
   |--data
   |    |-data.txt
```

How do I get the path name of `data.txt`?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is similar to that for pure Python as explained in:

- [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path)

as you can still look up `__file__` on a C extension object.

```
>>> import wrapt._wrappers
>>> wrapt._wrappers.__file__
'/Users/graham/Python/wrapt-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wrapt/_wrappers.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
```

In C code, you just need to work through the steps using the C API.

```
PyObject *module = NULL;
PyObject *file = NULL;

module = PyImport_ImportModule('package.module');

if (module) {
    PyObject *dict = NULL;

    dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);

    file = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "__file__");

    if (file) {
        ...
    }

    Py_XDECREF(file);
}

Py_XDECREF(module);
```

You then need to drop the last segment of the path to get the directory and construct the path to the other file. I don't show code for that, as depends on whether want to do it yourself in C code, or muck around with trying to call the `os.path` functions from Python.

Also, it is often better to wrap your C extension within a thin Python package wrapper. That way these sorts of things which are easier to do in Python code can be done there as a function. Your C API code can then call your pure Python function if it really needs to. In other words, can save yourself a lot of work by only putting the stuff that needs to be in C code in the extension and do other work in the Python wrapper.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Indeed, I am following your last paragraph to get the module path using python only. That way things are cleaner and easier.