# Python requests-html throwing multiprocessing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, multiprocessing, python-requests-html

I am attempting to move over my web scraping program from using the requests library to the requests-html library to allow me to render the javascript on webpages. On the import of the module this error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backend2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests_html
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyppeteer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.launcher import connect, launch, executablePath  # noqa: E402
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/browser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.page import Page
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.coverage import Coverage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/coverage.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.util import merge_dict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/util.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyppeteer.chromium_downloader import check_chromium, chromium_executable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyppeteer/chromium_downloader.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tqdm import tqdm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._tqdm import tqdm
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 75, in <module>
    mp_lock = mp.RLock()  # multiprocessing lock
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'RLock'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: there is a module named `multiprocessing` in your project.

Comment: I have not created any `multiprocessing` module within my project

Comment: check multiprocessing.__file__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3.7, but the github of requests-html states that [only Python 3.6 is supported](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) (bottom of page). I get all kinds of horrible errors when I try to use Python 3.7 but 3.6 works fine. So, seems strange I know, but please try using 3.6

Even so, as @georgexsh states, there should still be a `RLock` available for import from `multiprocessing` in 3.7 so it looks like your error may actually be that one of your code files is called `multiprocessing.py` or you have your own package called `multiprocessing` (so you are importing that instead of the module you wanted).

Comment: I think that may have helped a bit (using 3.6.6) though now the program is failing the import because `from multiprocessor import simpleQueue` throws an `ImportError: cannot import name SimpleQueue`. (I'll probably end up posting another question relating to this)

Comment: @S.Allen That should be `from multiprocessing import SimpleQueue`

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to me `multiprocessing`, I should have ctrl-c/v. I also tried reinstalling multiprocessing to no avail.

Comment: @S.Allen I am really suspicious that you have another module called multiprocessing somewhere in your path. What is the output if you follow the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/248862/9794932 using `multiprocessing` as `a_module` ?

Comment: I actually did which solved the problem. Somehow I managed to avoid scrolling down in the current working directory where there was a `multiprocessing.py` file, thanks.