# How to get the path of a python file which imports a certain package?

Tags: python, module

There are python files `a.py` and `b.py`. And `b.py` is imported in `a.py` by `import b`.
How to get the absolute path of `a.py` in `b.py` when `a.py` runs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a module's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path)

Answer (score 0):

## b.py

```
import os
import traceback


try: assert 0
except:
    st = traceback.format_stack()
     # format of st --> ['  File "filename", line 1, in <module>\n    import b\n', ... ... ]
    relative_p = st[0].split(',')[0].split(' ')[-1].split('"')[1]
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(relative_p)
    print(abs_path)
    # prints the importer's path, else if no importer, then itself's abs path

# rest of program goes here ...
```