# Where can I find the .py files of built-in modules?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I'd like to look at the code of the built-in 'math' module.
Where would I find this?

Answer (score 1):

You can search like this: "your module" + documentation. For example: Pygame documentation. You will get all the info you need from there. Otherwise you can use google. Python is a very popular language and there's information of all kind out there. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Question is already asked many times 
You can find the answer of where to find module path and it's digging time
[retrieve a module's path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/248862/11160255)