# Find path of a package (e.g. pandas) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

Is there a way to programmatically find the location of a python package once it is imported?

For example:

```
import os

import pandas

os.get_package_directory(panda)
>>> C:\Users\username\miniconda3\pkgs\pandas-1.0.5-py37h47e9c7a_0
```

Comment: Check this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this, but try this:

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__file__)
```