# list packages/modules and in which distrubution of python they are instaled, Ubuntu

Tags: python, list, ubuntu

I need to list all the installed packages for python, but the problem is that I have multiple versions of python and anaconda installed in my computer and I can't delete them and keep only one version.
So is there a way to list all installed packages/modules and in which version of python they are installed?
I used this command `pip list`  but it only lists the installed packages and their versions.
foe example:

```
scapy           python 3.5
pyinstaller     python 2.7
```

I found this command `python-which <package name>`; [How to retrieve a module's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path);  but it says bash: `python-which: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pythonX.X -m pip list` would show all the packages installed for that version of python.