# Vs code turtle programming for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, python-turtle

I just wanted to ask that does Vs code run its own python turtle or uses external python turtle which is installed with original python from python.org

Comment: Note that all versions of Python 2 have been [officially deprecated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) as of January 1st, 2020 and will no longer receive support or security updates. It's highly recommended that you migrate to Python 3.

Comment: You can check this yourself by [peaking at the modules path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path).

Comment: @Brian i already have python installed but due to some error in tk.py  i cannot use python anymore so instead i am using vs code

Comment: @Noobprogrammer -What is the code you are using? What is the error displayed by VS Code?

Comment: VSC has no python of its own. not even the MS-Python extension, it uses the installed Python versions on your host machine

Comment: @Jill Cheng  There is no error as the whole command is stuck and in VS code , code is working as it is intended but as it connects to my python turtle and all python files are corrupted so its gets unresponsive

Comment: @rioV8 I know that but i am just trying my luck everywhere :)

Comment: @Noobprogrammer -VS Code as an editor, when using the python module in it, we need to install it manually. The python module is stored in "\Lib\site-packages\" of the currently used python environment.

Comment: what do you mean with: `all python files are corrupted`

Comment: @rioV8 i just deleted a line from Tk.py folder as it was creating a error in my program but after deleting it, no command , option and even minimize , cut etc are not working for any program

Comment: @JillCheng I already tried but nothing happened

Comment: So when YOU write a program and it does not work the reason is that the modules you use are wrong? Have you looked at your nick name

Comment: @rioV8 its the first thing I do when I do when i open this website

Answer (score 0):

Turtle and other Python packages are not directly run by Visual Studio Code (VS Code). Rather, it depends on a third-party Python interpreter that is installed on your computer. The Python interpreter that you have set up in your Visual Studio Code environment is used when you create and run Python code in Visual Studio Code, including code that makes use of the Turtle module.

To use the Turtle module in Python, you generally don't need to install it separately if you are using the standard Python installation from Python.org, as Turtle is a part of the Python Standard Library.