# How to get the path of the file where get path function is called

Tags: python

I have two python files

file1.py at location /home/nitesh/loc1

```
import sys
SCRIPT_DIR = Path(sys.path[0])
```

file2.py at location /home/nitesh/loc2

```
from file1 import SCRIPT_DIR
```

I am calling file2.py. Expecting SCRIPT_DIR to  `/home/nitesh/loc1` but getting  `/home/nitesh/loc2`

How to acheive this

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path can help?

Comment: Using the special variable `__file__` you get: `SCRIPT_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent`.