# How do I find out the path of the currently executing script?

Tags: python

**Duplicate of: [In Python, how do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing)**

I would like to find out the path to the currently executing script.
I have tried os.getcwd() but that only returns the directory I ran the script from not the actual directory the script is stored.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I did do a search before I asked but never found that.
*shrug*
:)

Comment: not a big deal; it has happened to me as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168730/how-do-i-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-using-python-closed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, `__file__` identifies the current Python file. Thus:

```
print "I'm inside Python file %s" % __file__
```

will print the current Python file. Note that this works in imported Python modules, as well as scripts.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sys.path[0]

You can do something like
'print os.path.join(sys.path[0], sys.argv[0])'

https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html

Comment: Unlikely to actually be correct -- the running script may not be the first item on the path.  It could be in any of the locations on the PYTHONPATH.  Further, if it was started with python -m someModule, then argv[0] isn't relevant, either.

Comment: @S.Lott - From the docs that Pat linked: "the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter." so it should be correct for what I want but I have decided to use os.path.abspath(__file__) :)