# How do I get the path of the Python script I am running in?

Tags: python, path

> **Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, how do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executin)

How do I get the path of a the Python script I am running in? I was doing `dirname(sys.argv[0])`, however on Mac I only get the filename - not the full path as I do on Windows.

No matter where my application is launched from, I want to open files that are relative to my script file(s).

Comment: It seems that Jeff forgot that not all python scripts are modules, please nominate for reopening.

Comment: @sorin oh, but they are; a `module` object can be created for any script file. Just because something never actually gets `import`ed doesn't make it "not a module". The answer is the same, anyway: treat the script as a module (use some kind of bootstrap if really necessary) and then apply the same technique.

Comment: Yes, a script is a module, but this well-asked question should be re-opened. It has not been answered here, and the "duplicate" question is not a duplicate because it only answers how to get the location of a module you have loaded, not the one you are in.

Comment: see the "import inspect" solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executin

Comment: @acidzombie24 you **don't need the full path** to open and manipulate files from your directory. you can, for example, `open('images/pets/dog.png')` and Python will do the other.

Comment: I have a one line solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python/18489147#18489147

Comment: I have changed the duplicate links so that they point at actual duplicate questions - this question does not need to be reopened.

Comment: Simpler solution with explanation what is pwd https://hinty.io/brucehardywald/python-create-folder/

Answer (score 640):

Use this to get the path of the current file. It will resolve any symlinks in the path.

```python
import os

file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

This works fine on my mac. It won't work from the Python interpreter (you need to be executing a Python file).

Comment: Not so sure about that, here a result from OSX 10.6 `NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: Sorin: Perhaps you tried the expression in the shell?

Comment: I get the same and using it in a program not in the shell.
  File "C:\Python27\pydocs\cli_mate new\chimpbot.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.current_dict = os.path.realpath(__file__)+'\data\default_dict.dat'
    NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: Make a `chdir` before calling `realpath` and real path will fail, this is not the answer.

Comment: @Mr_Chimp It's `__file__`, not `file`. Does changing that fix it?

Comment: @jpmc26 I think the underscores got turned into bold formatting... That was three years ago though. I don't even remember what I was using this for :)

Comment: The `NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined` error just means you forgot to `import os`.

Comment: I noticed that if you put `os.chdir('somewhere/else/')` before hand, it somehow won't get the correct path. E.g. `os.chdir('..'); print os.path.realpath(__file__)`

Comment: When I `execfile("script.py")` then inside `script.py` `__file__` is not defined, but it is when I `import script`.

Comment: It may be worth adding that this only works if we're really excecuting the script, thus it doesn't work when just running the cell (e.g. in Spyder)

Comment: `NameError: __file__` ... And I *have* imported `os`. Not sure why this is the accepted answer..?

Comment: This will not work in shell.

Comment: The path contains the file name at the end, it's not just the path  :-(

Comment: same issue not working as sorin's comment

Comment: works fine in a script on GNU/Linux with Python3.X

Comment: works fine on my osx python3 and ubuntu, this anwser should be pushed on top, it maybe required python3 this should be added to the awnser too

Comment: Does this resolve symlinks of symlinks of symlinks, etc.?

Comment: Works fine when you are running it in a script, not in the IDLE editor

Answer (score 172):

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Comment: Thanks. This get the path of the .py file where the code is written, which is what I want, even though OP wanted another path.

Comment: This should be combined with information in the other answer: `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` will give the directory.

Comment: Thank you. Does it work for you on `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119454/how-to-obtain-jupyter-notebooks-path) to work on notebook

Answer (score 149):

7.2 of Dive Into Python: [Finding the Path](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/regression_path.html).

```
import sys, os

print('sys.argv[0] =', sys.argv[0])             
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])        
print('path =', pathname)
print('full path =', os.path.abspath(pathname))
```

Comment: I like how your answer shows a lot of different variations and features from python to solve the question.

Comment: Yes, and I like it better because it doesn't use `__` variables (I know it's just a convention for system names)

Comment: This **does not work** if you call the script via another script from another directory.

Comment: That's probably something we should tell the author.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea I see it does not work if we call it from another script in another directory. Then what is the solution?

Comment: @SorinSbarnea see the subject of the question: get the path of the **running** script (the script which has been executed). An `import`ed module is just a resource.

Comment: The question is not very clear, but your solution would work only if it is called at the beginning of the script (in order to be sure that nobody changes the current directory). I am inclined to use the inspect method instead. "running script" is not necessarily same as "called script" (entry point) or "currently running script".

Comment: This does also not work on UNIX if the script is in your PATH!

Comment: @sorin and Alex Please tell us how it does not work. If we know what it does do, that should help us to find a real solution.

Answer (score 60):

The accepted solution for this will not work if you are planning to compile your scripts using py2exe.  If you're planning to do so, this is the functional equivalent:

```
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Py2exe does not provide an `__file__` variable.  For reference:  http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment

Comment: Unluckily this does not work on Mac, as the OP says. Please see [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv): _it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not_

Comment: (it's incredibly complex to get a really cross-browser solution...)

Comment: @Stefano **that's not a problem**. To make sure it's an absolute (full) pathname, use `os.path.abspath(...)`

Comment: this doesn't give the location of the .py file of interest when I use a jupyter notebook

Answer (score -7):

If you have even the relative pathname (in this case it appears to be `./`) you can open files relative to your script file(s). I use Perl, but the same general solution can apply: I split the directory into an array of folders, then `pop` off the last element (the script), then `push` (or for you, `append`) on whatever I want, and then join them together again, and BAM! I have a working pathname that points to exactly where I expect it to point, relative or absolute.

Of course, there are better solutions, as posted. I just kind of like mine.

Comment: In python this does not work if you call the script from a completely different path, e.g. if you are in `~` and your script is in `/some-path/script` you'll get `./` equal to `~` and not `/some-path` as he asked (and I need too)

Comment: question was how to obtain the module's path, not how to build one pathname from another