# How to get self file name

Tags: python, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python, path of script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/python-path-of-script)

Is there any way that i can print the self filename of a file and current location.

Answer (score 15):

Could `__file__` be what you are looking for?