# How can I get the path of my python script?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the path of my python script.

I know 'sys.argv[0] gives me the path and the name of my python script.

how can I just get the path?

I tried:

```
 print sys.argv[0]
    path = sys.argv[0].split("/")
    scriptpath = "".join(path[0:-1])
```

But it does not add back the path separator.

Comment: change `"".join(path[0:-1])` to `"/".join(path[0:-1])` if you had to have that specific solution for whatever reason :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefer to use `__file__`, like this:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

*Note:* using `sys.argv[0]` may not work if you call the script via another script from another directory.

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work as intended, if you use PyInstaller, because it is unpacked into a temporary folder which then is (correctly) returned as the path of the `__file__`. In this case `dirname(realpath(sys.argv[0]))` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), in case you might have a relative pathame, you need [`os.path.abspath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) too

Answer (score 1):

Don't try string operations on paths, use the `os.path` module instead. E.g.:

```
scriptpath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

[From another Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/python-path-of-script)

```
import sys, os

print 'sys.argv[0] =', sys.argv[0]             
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])        
print 'path =', pathname
print 'full path =', os.path.abspath(pathname)
```