# Parse the executing file path

Tags: python, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path)
>   [python, path of script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/python-path-of-script)

I have a Python file, and I would like to parse the path when this file is executed.  If I run myPython.py like this:

```
python ~/Documents/Project/myPython.py
```

I would like to know the path "~/Documents/Project/" in the file myPython.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sys.argv[0]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is the path of your script as executed by Python. You can use [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to get just the directory name from that:

```
import sys, os
print os.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

It is OS-dependent if it is the full path entered on the command line; Mac OS X and Linux both include the path.

The path can, however, differ based on how Python invoked it. An alternative is to use `__file__`, and you can make the path absolute by using [`os.path.abspath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and [`os.path.expanduser()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to cover all variations:

```
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This example should prove helpful:

*test.py:*

```
import os

print 'Script directory: ' + os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print 'Working directory: ' + os.getcwd()
```

*Execution in terminal:*

```
$ cd ~
$ python ~/Desktop/test.py 
Script directory: /Users/tomas/Desktop
Working directory: /Users/tomas
```

Answer (score 0):

Just You have to need write two statement in py file:

```
          import sys
          print sys.argv[0]
```