# How can I load a configuration file based on the relative path from the script being executed?

Tags: python, path, relative-path

StackOverflow,

Below is the first few lines of my script:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
from docopt import docopt
import core as scrappy

ARGS = docopt(__doc__, version=scrappy.__version__)
if not ARGS['PATH']:
    ARGS['PATH'] = './'

# load config file
CFG = SafeConfigParser()
if not CFG.read(ARGS['--cfg']):  # call to CFG.read also loads file if it exists
    raise IOError('Configuration file not found.')
```

The configuration file I'm trying to read is in the same directory as the above script.  By default, docopt sets the path to this file to `./file.conf` (I have tested this with `file.conf` with identical results).

The last line of the script is always called, suggesting that the file can't be found.  I confirmed this by printing the output of `os.getcwd`, which revealed that the script's execution directory is whichever directory the terminal was pointing to.

What gives?

What can I do to point to the configuration file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `__file__` predefined module attribute. Like this:

```
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
CFG = SafeConfigParser()
cfg_full_path = os.path.join(module_dir, ARGS['--cfg'])
if not CFG.read(cfg_full_path): 
    ...
```

Comment: why should I prefer this method over using `sys.argv`?  What's the advantage?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/595317/1929432) they say it doesn't always work.