# How do I find the path of the file I am running on any operating system? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-the-python-script-i-am-running-in%22this%22) that has answers that work on mac, but do they work on Windows, Linux, etc? I am referring specifically to `os.path.realpath(__file__)` or `os.path.realpath('myPythonFile.py')`.

I apologize for this question being so obvious to figure out but I don't have access to non-mac computers and so can't test it myself.

Comment: Just use a linux virtual machine for your tests, it's costless.

Comment: There's always `sys.argv[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [reference docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html) that method should work fine for all operating systems.

Specifically from the docs:

> Note Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The `os.path` module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try this one too

```
import os
import sys
f_name = os.getcwd() + sys.argv[0]
print f_name
```