# Python will access external config file unless script is open from root directory of script

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am new to python and linux. Below is the issue I am having.

If I open terminal window and go to directory that has my .py file and run the script everything works fine.

If I try running the script from any other directory using path to the .py file I get an error saying it couldnt find the external `config.py` file my script uses.

example:
My `a.py` script and `config.py` are in `/home/pi/m`

If I am in directory `pi@raspberrypi:/home/pi/m` and call my .py file everything works

If I am in directory `pi@raspberrypi:/` and run command `python /home/pi/m/a.py` the script doesn't execute and states it can't find my `config.py` file

What causes this behavior and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is the config file in your script configured as a full path or a relative path?

Comment: How are you referencing the `config.py` file in your code?

Comment: Related: [How do I get the path of the Python script I am running in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-the-python-script-i-am-running-in)

Answer (score 0):

I tried what you are speaking of.It works on my system.Assuming you are doing `import config`.

```
[raa@raa ~]$ python ./Desktop/test.py
Ok
[raa@raa ~]$ python ./Desktop/test.py
Config
Ok
[raa@raa ~]$ python /Desktop/test.py
python: can't open file '/Desktop/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[raa@raa ~]$
```

I am doing this in `test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import config

print('Ok')
```

And this in `config.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print('Config')
```

Comment: It is the `config.py` that is not being found by the `my.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of `a.py`:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

This will extend the search for modules to be imported to the local folder of `a.py`.