# How to save file to folder with the name of current Python script file?

Tags: python-3.x, path, save

I have a Python 3 `test.py` script where some data is created which I want to save to a file with a user-defined name, say `data.csv`. The folder in which this script is sitting has a `/Results` folder inside it. What I want to do is to create a subfolder inside `Results` with the name of the current script and store my file inside it. So, what I want is my file to be stored in `./Results/test/data.csv`. I want these folders to be created if they don't previously exist and if they do exist, along with the file, I want `data.csv` to be replaced. I want this to work on any OS. How should this be done "pythonically"?

```
~/
  test.py
  Results/
     test/
        data.csv
```

Here's a test code where `data.csv` is not being saved where I want it. How should I edit it?

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "data.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df.to_csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `os.path` module to do a series of folder checking and make the folder if not exist. And then you can access the current filename by using the `__file__` attribute.

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd

file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__)))[0]

full_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "Results")

if not os.path.exists(full_path):
    os.mkdir(full_path)

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(full_path, file_name)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(full_path, file_name))

file_location = os.path.join(full_path, file_name, 'data.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
df.to_csv(file_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
import platform
import os

if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
    print("%s" % os.path.expandvars("%USERPROFILE%"))
elif platform.system().lower() == 'posix':
    print("%s" % os.path.expandvars("$PATH")) #or some other posix var like USER...
else:
    print("What the heck type of os is this?!?")
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-the-python-script-i-am-running-in?rq=1) may also be useful for you.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Can you check the added code in my question and show me how it's done?

Comment: Sorry about that, was using on a school computer so I couldn't test it. I'll test it now.