# How to get .py file to run from directory of file instead of workspace directory in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode to write Python and when I run .py files they run from wirectory of workspace.
 How can I get the file to run from the files dricetory instead of workspace directory? 
I have tried setting this on: `python.terminal.executeInFileDir` in settings but that did not change anything. On https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference their explanation of this is exactly what I am trying to do but it does not work.
I have also tried several different variables in launch.json such as `"cwd": "{$fileDirname}`, `"cwd": "{$file}`, `"cwd": "{$fileDirname}`. 
My launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal", 
        "cwd": "{$fileDirname}"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Where do you place those `"cwd"` key-value pairs? Can you share your whole launch.json with us?

Comment: The `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` option should work

Comment: launch.json is now added to post.

Comment: analyze the command typed in the terminal to see what you should put in the `cwd` field

Comment: @vetle your launch.json seems right. Another way to possibly solve your problems is making you script current working directory independent, everywhere you are using a path you can get it relative to the current python file using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-python-script-i-am-running-in. If nothing works maybe try to update or reinstall your vscode.

Answer (score 0):

When I set `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,` in "`settings.json`", and open a new VSCode terminal, VSCode automatically enters the folder directory where the currently executed script is located when the file is executed:

[image]