# Get the directory holding the file that I am currently executing

Tags: python, operating-system, chdir

I have a file `main.py` stored in `~/project1/code/`.

In `main.py`, I have changed the working directory to import some other .py files:

```
import os 
os.chdir('~/project2/code/')
```

Afterwards, I want to point the working directory to the location where `main.py` is located. However, since I might run `main.py` from several directories, I don't want to hard-code the location. How can I retrieve the directory that holds the file that I am currently executing?

When I run the provided solutions from here [How do I get the path of the Python script I am running in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-python-script-i-am-running-in), I get the following error:

```
file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-138-c9fbde97a5bf>", line 1, in <module>
    file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the path of the Python script I am running in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-python-script-i-am-running-in)

Comment: No, this raises: `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: It will be defined when you run the file as a script. Apparently you are executing this code in an interactive ipython session?

Comment: I see, thank you. Currently, I am testing it in Spyder indeed. But I will run it from the terminal, so then it should work. Thanks