# How to get the name of a running Python script?

Tags: python

How do I get the name of a running Python script?

I tried `os.__file__` but that returns the name of the file where `os` resides.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4152963/2336725 seems to be a better duplicate.

Answer (score 24):

```
>> import os
>> import sys
>> print sys.argv[0]
```

or if you just want the script and not the full path

```
>>
>> print os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
thisFile = __file__
```

It's magic!

Comment: I get ```NameError: name '__file__' is not defined```.

Comment: Which Python implementation are you using? CPython or something else?

Comment: Python 2.7.3. I just ran "python" then `print __file__`.

Comment: @bos I don't think you can get it from interactive mode, need to be run as a file.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what you mean by "a running python script".

`__file__` will give you the name of the currently executing file. If that's a module, you'll get where it was imported from e.g. blahblah.pyc

`sys.argv[0]` will give you the name of the script that is being run, even if called from a module that that script imported.

Please do look up the answers to the earlier question on this topic (see S.Lott's comment on your question).

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv[0]` should give you the name of the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
import __main__
print __main__.__file__
```

This will print the current filename which is running

Answer (score -1):

```
sys.path[0]
```

returns the path of the script that launched the Python interpreter.

If you read this script directly, it will return the path of the script. If the script was imported from another script, it will return the path of that script.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just tested. This gave me `K:/code/allRequirementsTests` which is the absolute path of the script, minus the extension