# Get name of current script in Python

Tags: python, scripting, basename

I'm trying to get the name of the Python script that is currently running.

I have a script called `foo.py` and I'd like to do something like this in order to get the script name:

```py
print(Scriptname)
```

Comment: `Path(__file__).name` since Python3.4+.

Answer (score 950, accepted):

You can use [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/import.html#__file__) to get the name of the current file. When used in the main module, this is the name of the script that was originally invoked.

If you want to omit the directory part (which might be present), you can use `os.path.basename(__file__)`.

Comment: Python 3.2: "`Exception NameError: NameError("global name '__file__' is not defined",)`"

Comment: @sdaau: `__file__` is not defined in the interactive interpreter, because it is meaningless there.  It is set by the import implementation, so if you use a non-standard import mechanism it might also be unset.

Comment: At least for Python 2.7, I believe an `import os` is required for this to work. I'd add this into the answer.

Comment: Actually, `import os.path`.

Comment: @cdunn2001: `import os` and `import os.path` are completely equivalent.

Comment: @sven-marnach: Oh, [you're right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724348/should-i-use-import-os-path-or-import-os). I've been Doing It Wrong for years!

Comment: you use `os.path` if you want to import only listed functions, for example `from os.path import join` or especially if you want to give them an alias - for example `from os.path import join as path_join`

Comment: This, in general, will absolutely not work. That's because the code that's executing may be in a separate library, where __file__ will just give you the name of that library file, not the currently executing script, which is what is being asked for. Granted, the question SEEMS to refer to code executing in the main script, but what's clear is that it's the name of the current script that's desired and any solution should work in all cases. See later answers.

Comment: @JohnDeighan Ok, ok, no need to get upset. There is no solution that works in all circumstances. The value of `sys.argv[0]` can be arbitrarily set when the process is created, so it won't work in general. Importing `__main__` doesn't always work for various reasons. In my opinion, you shouldn't need the path of the current script, and if you absolutely do, you should retrieve it in the main module using `__file__`. Granted, I didn't discuss any of that in this answer, since most people just want something easy that works in the common case.

Comment: all the answers are great, but fail under certain circumstances. What if the script was called by setup.py test , what if the script is called by doctest, pytest or by uwsgi ?
To add a new possibility, aside __main__.__file__, sys.argv - You can also inspect the stack for the called program filename.
And - You should check probably the result - does that file exist ? 
I put all that solutions together in a short library, 
see : https://github.com/bitranox/lib_programname

Comment: @bitranox Thanks! What's the use case you have in mind for this library? I understand it returns the name of the main script, but why would anyone want that information in all these circumstances?

Comment: @sven-marnach: I have many use cases for that - for instance logging, restart processes (since You can not rely on the process list) and so on. And since I do TDD, I want that the main script name is also correct in my tests. 
Of course, You can do it manually, from case to case different, but for me it is easier to have one small library which delivers the correct name under all circumstances - even  when running "setup.py test", "pytest", "doctest in pycharm", "uwsgi" and so on.
Also it provides an easy to use, do not think twice method for the community, so why not share it.

Comment: @bitranox Hmm, I don't quite understand the use cases. For logging, I generally create loggers local to each module or component, and then let the main script set up the logging config to decide what's happening with the logs. "Restart processes" – this is also unclear to me. How would that work when running tests? And don't get me wrong: I don't mind it's useful for you. I'm just trying to understand whether it would be useful for _me_ as well. :)

Comment: @sven-marnach - well, if You dont know if You need it, then You probably dont need it ;-) I have a huge codebase with a lot of different tests in pytest, doctest and so on, and in some cases I need to get the name (or lets better say the full pathlib.Path) of the main script reliably, even under test conditions. Or imagine You need to find a configuration file that lives in a directory relative to where the application startup script is located. Also it reads cleaner in the code. A lot of people seem to need it, see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499

Comment: @sven_marnach: btw, its changing in python3.9 again : the __file__ attribute of the __main__ module became an absolute path, rather than a relative path. These paths now remain valid after the current directory is changed by os.chdir()

So I really only want to change it in ONE place, rather then scanning my code were it should/can be changed ...

Comment: I've come up with a one-liner:
`filename =  __file__.split('/')[-1]`
or
`filetitle = __file__.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]`

Answer (score 240):

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

This will print `foo.py` for `python foo.py`, `dir/foo.py` for `python dir/foo.py`, etc. It's the first argument to `python`. (Note that after py2exe it would be `foo.exe`.)

Comment: @DenisMalinovsky: define "won't work". If you call `python linkfile.py`, where `linkfile.py` is a symlink to `realfile.py`, `sys.argv[0]` will be `'linkfile.py'`, which may or may not be what you want; it is certainly what I *expect*. `__file__` is the same: it will be `linkfile.py`. If you want to find `'realfile.py'` from `'linkfile.py'`, try `os.path.realpath('linkfile.py')`.

Comment: +1 because it's (a) a little neater and (b) will still work in module (where the __file__ variable would be the module file, not the executed one).

Comment: This answer is nice because it works in IDLE too. As a note, to get just the filename, you can write os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

Comment: More importantly, this doesn't work except from inside the main file.  Do not use this, use `__file__` instead.

Comment: WHAT!!! Did you even try this? Exactly the opposite is true. The questioner asked for the name of the python script that is running - not the python file which is currently executing. Imagine that  you have a script that, when an error occurs, prints the script name along with allowed arguments. You put that in a function, using one of these 2 techniques. At some point, you decide to move the function to an external library. Would you want to print the name of the main script running, or the name of the library file that's executing?

Comment: This is the right solution when you want to print out a usage info because this is exactly how the program is called, while __file__ is not.

Comment: This answer is wrong, if that python script is a module located in a package and is being imported, `sys.argv[0]` will print the name of the "importer" and not the "importee" (which is the Python script containing the `sys.argv[0]`).

Comment: @aderchox: that it’s giving the *script* (the entry point), not the file, is the whole point, as the comments here also clearly show. The question was ambiguous, this is the correct answer for one of its possible interpretations—the most commonly desired, I suspect.

Comment: This one combined with the accepted answer is good to get the python process name on an imported module: `os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])`

Answer (score 159):

For completeness' sake, I thought it would be worthwhile summarizing the various possible outcomes and supplying references for the exact behaviour of each.

The answer is composed of four sections:

1. A list of different approaches that return the full path to the currently executing script.
2. A caveat regarding handling of relative paths.
3. A recommendation regarding handling of symbolic links.
4. An account of a few methods that could be used to extract the actual file name, with or without its suffix, from the full file path.

---

#### Extracting the full file path

- `__file__` is the currently executing file, as detailed in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-43):

  > `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The `__file__` attribute may be missing for certain types of modules, such as *C* modules that are statically linked into the interpreter; for extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library, it is the pathname of the shared library file.

  [From *Python3.4*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes) onwards, per [issue 18416](https://bugs.python.org/issue18416), `__file__` is always an absolute path, unless the currently executing file is a script that has been executed directly (not via the interpreter with the `-m` command line option) using a relative path.
- `__main__.__file__` (requires importing `__main__`) simply accesses the aforementioned `__file__` attribute of the [main module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__), e.g. of the script that was invoked from the command line.

  [From *Python3.9*](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#other-language-changes) onwards, per [issue 20443](https://bugs.python.org/issue20443), the `__file__` attribute of the `__main__` module became an absolute path, rather than a relative path.
- `sys.argv[0]` (requires importing `sys`) is the script name that was invoked from the command line, and might be an absolute path, as detailed in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

  > `argv[0]` is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the `-c` command line option to the interpreter, `argv[0]` is set to the string `'-c'`. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, `argv[0]` is the empty string.

  As mentioned in [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152992/3903832), *Python* scripts that were converted into stand-alone executable programs via tools such as [*py2exe*](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [*PyInstaller*](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) might not display the desired result when using this approach (i.e. `sys.argv[0]` would hold the name of the executable rather than the name of the main *Python* file within that executable).
- If none of the aforementioned options seem to work, probably due to an atypical execution process or an irregular import operation, the [*inspect* module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) might prove useful, as suggested in [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120068/3903832):

  ```
  import inspect
  source_file_path = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
  ```

  However, [inspect.currentframe()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) would raise an exception when running in an implementation without *Python* stack frame.

  Note that [inspect.getfile(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile) is preferred over [inspect.getsourcefile(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile) because the latter [raises a TypeError exception](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/0596001886/re726.html) when it can determine only a binary file, not the corresponding source file (see also [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761378/3903832)).
- From *Python3.6* onwards, and as detailed in [another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119753/3903832), it's possible to install an external open source library, [*lib_programname*](https://github.com/bitranox/lib_programname), which is tailored to provide a complete solution to this problem.

  This library iterates through all of the approaches listed above until a valid path is returned. If all of them fail, it raises an exception. It also tries to address various pitfalls, such as invocations via the [*pytest*](https://docs.pytest.org/) framework or the [*pydoc*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) module.

  ```
  import lib_programname
  # this returns the fully resolved path to the launched python program
  path_to_program = lib_programname.get_path_executed_script()  # type: pathlib.Path
  ```

---

#### Handling relative paths

When dealing with an approach that happens to return a relative path, it might be tempting to invoke various path manipulation functions, such as [`os.path.abspath(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) or [`os.path.realpath(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) in order to extract the full or real path.

However, these methods rely on the current path in order to derive the full path. Thus, if a program first changes the current working directory, for example via [`os.chdir(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir), and only then invokes these methods, they would return an incorrect path.

---

#### Handling symbolic links

If the current script is a symbolic link, then all of the above would return the path of the symbolic link rather than the path of the real file and `os.path.realpath(...)` should be invoked in order to extract the latter.

---

#### Further manipulations that extract the actual file name

[`os.path.basename(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) may be invoked on any of the above in order to extract the actual file name and [`os.path.splitext(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) may be invoked on the actual file name in order to truncate its suffix, as in `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(...))`.

From [*Python 3.4*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pathlib) onwards, per [PEP 428](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428), the [*`PurePath`* class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) of the [*`pathlib`* module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) may be used as well on any of the above. Specifically, [`pathlib.PurePath(...).name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) extracts the actual file name and [`pathlib.PurePath(...).stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) extracts the actual file name without its suffix.

Answer (score 69):

Note that `__file__` will give the file where this code resides, which can be imported and different from the main file being interpreted. To get the main file, the special [__main__](http://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) module can be used:

```
import __main__ as main
print(main.__file__)
```

Note that `__main__.__file__` works in Python 2.7 but not in 3.2, so use the import-as syntax as above to make it portable.

Comment: This works in many cases but not when I am using the `rPython` package from `R` language. That must be an exceptional case that is just too hard to handle.

Comment: Indeed, the rPython package embeds the python interpreter, which means there isn't a 'main' file like there is when python is running on its own (you'll find the same behaviour anytime python is embedded).  It does import `__main__` internally, for use in passing variables between `R` and `python`, so it would be relatively easy to make it set `__main__.__file__` before calling anything else, but I'm not even sure what would be an appropriate value in this case.

Comment: This does not work in an interactive terminal like iPython.  I get the following result import __main__ as main
print(main.__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [150] in <cell line: 2>
    print(main.__file__)

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'

Answer (score 58):

The Above answers are good . But I found this method more efficient using above results.
This results in actual script file name not a path.

```
import sys    
import os    
file_name =  os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: I like to split off the extension too, so I use:
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]

Comment: for me some years later with Python 3.8 this prints ipykernel_launcher.py and not the filename.

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 38):

For modern Python versions (3.4+), `Path(__file__).name` should be more idiomatic. Also, `Path(__file__).stem` gives you the script name without the `.py` extension.

Comment: NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

Comment: You should `from pathlib import Path` first.

Comment: "modern" means Python 3.x ?

Comment: @einpoklum `pathlib` was introduced in Python 3.4, so it should work starting from Python 3.4.

Comment: This code throws an error:  Path(__file__).name
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [155] in <cell line: 1>
    Path(__file__).name

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: Its `__file__` not file

Answer (score 14):

As of Python 3.5 you can simply do:

```
from pathlib import Path
Path(__file__).stem
```

See more here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem

For example, I have a file under my user directory named `test.py` with this inside:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path(__file__).stem)
print(__file__)
```

running this outputs:

```
>>> python3.6 test.py
test
test.py
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're doing an unusual import (e.g., it's an options file), try:

```
import inspect
print (inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
```

Note that this will return the absolute path to the file.

Comment: this is what finally worked when the current file is invoked from `env.SConscript` in platform.io build system.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
print __file__
```

Comment: This needs context.  It throws an error as is:   print(__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [156] in <cell line: 1>
    print(__file__)

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Answer (score 8):

we can try this to get current script name without extension.

```
import os

script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this without importing os or other libs.

If you want to get the path of current python script, use: `__file__`

If you want to get only the filename without .py extension, use this:

```
__file__.rsplit("/", 1)[1].split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

all that answers are great, but have some problems You might not see at the first glance.

lets define what we want - we want the name of the script that was executed, not the name of the current module - so `__file__` will only work if it is used in the executed script, not in an imported module.
`sys.argv` is also questionable - what if your program was called by pytest ? or pydoc runner ? or if it was called by uwsgi ?

and - there is a third method of getting the script name, I havent seen in the answers - You can inspect the stack.

Another problem is, that You (or some other program) can tamper around with `sys.argv` and `__main__.__file__` - it might be present, it might be not. It might be valid, or not. At least You can check if the script (the desired result) exists !

the library [lib_programname](https://github.com/bitranox/lib_programname) does exactly that :

- check if `__main__` is present
- check if `__main__.__file__` is present
- does give `__main__.__file__` a valid result (does that script exist ?)
- if not: check sys.argv:
- is there pytest, docrunner, etc in the sys.argv ? --> if yes, ignore that
- can we get a valid result here ?
- if not: inspect the stack and get the result from there possibly
- if also the stack does not give a valid result, then throw an Exception.

by that way, my solution is working so far with `setup.py test`, `uwsgi`, `pytest`, `pycharm pytest` , `pycharm docrunner (doctest)`, `dreampie`, `eclipse`

there is also a nice blog article about that problem from Dough Hellman, "Determining the Name of a Process from Python"

BTW, it will change again in python 3.9 : the **file** attribute of the **main** module became an absolute path, rather than a relative path. These paths now remain valid after the current directory is changed by os.chdir()

So I rather want to take care of one small module, instead of skimming my codebase if it should be changed somewere ...

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the lib_programname library.</sup>

Comment: With your permission, I've upvoted your answer and referred to it and to the library in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514032/3903832), which will hopefully increase their exposure.

Comment: @Yoel: thank You for that. In case of any issue with that library - please let me know, then i will update quickly

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP asked for the name of the current script file I would prefer

```
import os
os.path.split(sys.argv[0])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get script path in base class, use this code, subclass will get script path correctly.

```
sys.modules[self.__module__].__file__
```