# inspect.getfile () vs inspect.getsourcefile()

Tags: python

I was just going through the inspect module docs.

What exactly is the difference between:

```
inspect.getfile()
```

and

```
inspect.getsourcefile()
```

I get exactly the same file path (of the module) for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[getfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile):

> Return the name of the (text or binary) file in which an object was defined. This will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in module, class, or function.

`getfile()` also returns pyc (compiled) files, where as `getsourcefile()` will only return source files.

Comment: What is it's behavior on objects defined in C-extensions?

Comment: @agf: Try it. I get a `TypeError: <built-in function array> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object`