# Python: save script for information together with analysis

Tags: python

Quite often I do an anlysis with certain settings and store the plots or results in a folder which is separated from the codebase. To keep track of chosen settings I save the script like so:

```
import MyClass as my

model = my(some_parameters)
model.run()

with open(os.path.join(save_path, 'used_script_for_docu.py'), 'w') as copied_script_file:
    with open(os.path.abspath(__file__), 'r') as script_file:
        script_content = script_file.read()
    copied_script_file.write(script_content)
```

Is it somehow possible to add a function to MyClass which can save the script file like explained above? Can the instance of MyClass (`model`) somehow acces the script file with the current parameters settings? Or are there any other methods to save the script automatically without having to type/copy the lines from above from script to script?

EDIT: I would prefer to store the script file and not the states/parameters of the model because the script might contain settings/procedures which were not anticipated in beforehand and can threfore not be saved automatically from the namespace of e.g. `model`

Comment: (1) *Is it somehow possible to add a function to MyClass […]* - yes, of course. Did you try it? What was the problem? (2) It would probably be easier and more maintainable/scalable to use some sort of version control (e.g. Git) for the scripts and store a reference to the specific revision with the results; or use a dedicated configuration management system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321100/best-way-to-have-a-python-script-copy-itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to have a python script copy itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321100/best-way-to-have-a-python-script-copy-itself)