# Is there a way to detect if a block of code in the script itself contains a specific word

Tags: python

... and decide execution of that block based on the presence of that word?

For example I have this:

```
for frame in range(10):
    with open('frame_init.gro', 'w') as g:
        # do something
    with open('frame_next.gro', 'w') as h:
        # do something
```

When "frame" reaches 9, I don't want the whole `with open('frame_next.gro', 'w') as h` block to execute at all. Of course I have considered just encasing it in a `if frame !=  9` but my actual entire code is really long so it would be nice if I could just scan my script within the script itself if it is possible.

For those curious about what other things `frame_next.gro` is involved in, the answer is lots of calculations

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve with it?

Comment: wow, this is actually really condescending. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
a = 0
b = 1
print a + b

with open(__file__, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    val = int(lines[0].split(' = ')[-1])
    new_line = 'a = {}'.format(val+1)
    new_file = '\n'.join([new_line] + lines[1:])

with open(__file__, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([new_line] + lines[1:]))
```

From here:
[How can I make a python script change itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643428/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-change-itself)