# python how to get a running script's file name in import package

Tags: python

l have two scripts:

`main.py`

```
import package.py
```

`package.py`

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(_file_))
```

my excepted output is `main.py`, but the fact is `package.py`.

So how can l get the running script's file name in a package script?

**extra description**:

the truth is, l have a decorator function in `package.py`. it will generate a file at current path and named as the file's name who called it

Comment: Since that code is within the file `package.py` you could just hard-code it (not saying there is no better solution).

Comment: What are you exactly trying to accomplish? I see that package.py calls the print, what's the link between package and main that you want to print? You want to print the name of a script as soon as you import it?

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp the really l wanna to do is, l packaged some function into package,py, but the function of one of these functions need to get current running python script's filename(in my usage, running python script is main.py).

Comment: import sys print sys.argv[0] See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152963/get-the-name-of-current-script-with-python

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @pyd l have been said my excepted output is `main.py` in my description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use arguments to work it out.

```
from sys import argv
print(argv[0])
```

The first argument listed will be the command used to execute your script.
So if you're running `./main.py` then that's what you'll get.

If you're running it via python (such as `python main.py`) then (at least according to my testing) you'll get the full path. You can use the tools in `os.path` to pluck out just the filename if required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
print(os.path.basename(__name__))
```

Comment: No, it failed, still print `package.py`

Answer (score 1):

try:

main.py:

```
import package.py
```

---

package.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the entire path to the importing script, do this:

```py
import os
import sys
# get working directory
dir = os.getcwd()
# get script path as passed to python
script = sys.argv[0]
# if path is not absolute, then join with current dir
importing_script = os.path.join(dir,script) if not os.path.isabs(script) else script

# Your importing script is...
print(importing_script)
```