# Trying to sprint %s %d using python

Tags: python-3.x, special-characters

Problem statement :- I am searching for a tool that automatically include a line in c functions , line is printf("%s",**FILE**); , since i do not found any tool i decided to write my own script that write line at start of every function .

i am trying to print statement `printf("%s",__FILE__);` using python

```
print(   printf("%s",__FILE__);   )
```

I am facing issue when trying to print double quotes and %s , i have tried raw(r) but it doesn't help.

Comment: So you want to print the script's name? If so, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152963/get-name-of-current-script-in-python) might help you.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do, how you try to do it, and what error you get. The code shown is not valid syntax, regardless of quotes or ``%s``; please provide a [mcve]. Did you mean to ``print('printf("%s",__FILE__);')``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  i am trying to include  printf("%s",__FILE__);  for every function in c source code , i thought to automate this process as it takes days to include printf("%s",__FILE__);  manually

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Your suggestion worked well only issue when i include printf("%s\n",__FILE__);   \n  is not working properly

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? Does it result in unexpected output? Does it throw an error?

Comment: as soon as \n is executed standard output goes to new line . please this at your end print('printf("%s\n",__FILE__);')

Comment: Well, yes of course ``\n`` creates a new line – that literally is what it means. Do you want to print a literal ``\`` followed by a literal ``n``? As in ``print('printf("%s\\n",FILE);')``?

Comment: Just use this, we have to use a back slash to escape the characters

print("    printf(\"%s\",__FILE__);    " )

Comment: Look folks, when posting code in comments please use \`\`code quotes\`\`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
print('    printf("%s",__FILE__); ')
```