# Check the name of the module (not necessarily the file) that was used to run Python

Tags: python

If you invoke `python foo.py` or `python -m foo`, is there a way to detect, from inside Python, that the file `foo.py` / the module `foo` was used to run the program?

The docs for [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) suggest that `sys.argv[0]` can be used for this purpose, but it only works part-way. In my testing, invoking `python -m foo` still populates `sys.argv[0]` with the full filename of `foo.py`, *not* the module name `foo`, so it doesn't do what I would want it to do in all cases. I believe that this is also equivalent to `__file__`. It is very error-prone to try and extract a fully qualified module name from a filename.

I want to be able to distinguish between cases like `python a/b/c.py` and `python -m a.b.c`, as well as invoking Python with a "wrapper" like `python -m unittest a.b.c`. I do not want to rely on heuristics on `sys.argv[0]`, if at all possible.

**In reply to the comments and close votes**: I am not interested in workarounds; I have some already. I am asking this question because it want to know if this very specific thing is possible, not because I want help with my work in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get name of current script in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152963/get-name-of-current-script-in-python)

Comment: Not quite, see my edit @mkrieger1. I'm not sure if it's universally correct to assume that the module name is just the script name with `.py` removed.

Comment: Do you mean which interpreter was used? In that case sys.executable is probably what you are after.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: @Chris I am writing an application that needs to behave a certain way depending on how it was invoked. Regardless, I think this is a perfectly legitimate Python question as it stands.

Comment: A generic "I need it" isn't terribly helpful in explaining your actual requirements. What's the difference between `python foo.py` and `python -m foo` that you are trying to get at? Context is always helpful.

Comment: `__name__` will be `"__main__"` in a directly-run script, but I assume it's the module name if you use `python -m`.

Comment: @Chris suffice it to say that I want to know the difference between `python a/b/c.py` and `python -m a.b.c`. I also want to know the difference between `python -m a.b.c` and `python -m unittest`; I'd rather not resort to heuristics about the filename.

Comment: I appreciate your desire to help me solve my real-world problem, but I insist that this is a valid question on its own. I can figure out other ways to achieve "Y" if I need to. I am asking about "X" with the intention to learn about "X".

Comment: @Chris moreover, my hope was also that an answer to this question might be useful to _other_ people in the future; that's part of the purpose of SO, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html) says:

> When called with `-m module-name`, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script

[and](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

> Search [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) for the named module and execute its contents as the [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) module.

I understand that to mean that `-m module-name` is simply shorthand for `python module_name.py`, where `module_name.py` is the file in `sys.path` where Python is able to locate a module named `module-name`.

---

As an interesting side note, the documentation also says

> The module name should be a valid absolute Python module name, but the implementation may not always enforce this (e.g. it may allow you to use a name that includes a hyphen).

but it uses `module-name` as its example module.

Answer (score 4):

It is fairly easy to distinguish between `python a.py` and `python -m a` by looking at the `__package__` variable:

a.py:

```
print(repr(__package__))
```

```
$ python a.py
None

$ python -m a
''
```

In order to distinguish `python -m a` from `python -m unittest a` we can use `__name__`.

a.py:

```
print(__name__)
```

```
$ python -m a
__main__

$ python -m unittest a
a
```

I don't know how to get "unittest" from the last invocation without using `sys.argv` heuristics.

Comment: Very interesting observation about `__package__`. Even if the official answer is "no you can't", that might be useful for some cases, e.g. warning users if they invoke your program incorrectly.

Comment: @shadowtalker, strange that you accepted my answer when mkrieger1 provides a way to do the thing I said was not possible. If I were you, I'd accept this answer instead.

Comment: @Chris the last case is actually the case I am most interested in, distinguishing between `python -m a` and `python -m unittest a`. So unfortunately the answer really is "no, it's not possible" for the most general case. I appreciate both of your answers.