# How do I get the parent directory in Python?

Tags: python

Could someone tell me how to get the parent directory of a path in Python in a cross platform way. E.g.

```
C:\Program Files ---> C:\
```

and

```
C:\ ---> C:\
```

If the directory doesn't have a parent directory, it returns the directory itself. The question might seem simple but I couldn't dig it up through Google.

Comment: Related: [How do I get the path and name of the python file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50499/4561887)

Answer (score 783, accepted):

## **Python 3.4**

Use the `pathlib` module.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("/here/your/path/file.txt")
print(path.parent.absolute())
```

## **Old answer**

Try this:

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(yourpath, os.pardir))
```

where `yourpath` is the path you want the parent for.

Comment: Your answer is correct but convoluted; `os.path.dirname` is the function for this, like `a+=5-4` is more convoluted than `a+=1`. The question requested only the parent directory, not whether is exists or the *true* parent directory assuming symbolic links get in the way.

Comment: I tried to change the code snippet to `os.pardir`, but unfortunately Stack Overflow "Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters". It seems smart enough to detect whitespace padding; maybe the OP can correct this someday...

Comment: @tzot: unfortunately `os.path.dirname` gives different results depending on whether a trailing slash is included in the path. If you want reliable results you need to use the `os.path.join` method in answer above.

Comment: @Artfunkel Thanks. Your comment should be appended in the answer for its completeness' sake.

Comment: @tzot: I guess the OP wanted to know how to move from one subdirectory to its parent. But `dirname` only returns the directory part of the full pathname to a *file* by removing the last component auf the path string (here: `..`/`pardir`) via `split`. `abspath` on the other hand correctly interprets and resolves `..` as a reference to the top-level directory, which, I guess, is what the OP really asked for.

Comment: Since this is apparently complicated enough to warrant a StackOverflow question, I feel that this should be added to the os.path library as a built-in function.

Comment: Don't miss @benjarobin's solution below if you are interested to keep relative path relative.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are trying to work with paths on a different file system

Comment: Try `from pathlib import Path` and next `print((Path().parent.absolute()).parent)`

Comment: `Path("/here/your/path/file.txt")`  does not work. Error message: `'WindowsPath' object is not callable`

Comment: I prefer ```os.path.dirname``` since it gave me the path in linux format when converting back to string. May not matter for most people but the Pathlib way gave me it back in stinky windows format on my pc

Comment: Works fine. 
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(yourpath, os.pardir)))

No need 'pathlib', enough os packages.

Answer (score 404):

Using `os.path.dirname`:

```
>>> os.path.dirname(r'C:\Program Files')
'C:\\'
>>> os.path.dirname('C:\\')
'C:\\'
>>>
```

Caveat: `os.path.dirname()` gives different results depending on whether a trailing slash is included in the path. This may or may not be the semantics you want. Cf. @kender's answer using `os.path.join(yourpath, os.pardir)`.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(r'C:\Program Files')` what?  Python's just giving you the directory where the file 'Program Files' would be.  What's more, it doesn't even have to exist, behold: `os.path.dirname(r'c:\i\like\to\eat\pie')` outputs `'c:\\i\\like\\to\\eat'`

Comment: The original poster does not state that the directory have to exist. There are a lot of pathname methods that does nothing but string manipulation. 

To verify if the pathname actually exist requires a disk access. Depends on the application this may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Seems that this would be a good solution if you knew that the input directory was valid (which can be checked).

Comment: Most of the other provided solutions don't check if the parent exists either (as most os.path functions are indeed string manipulations _only_), so no big loss here. And all the other solutions here seem unnecessary complex to me, so I'm upvoting this one :)

Btw, imho the os.path is one of the worst classes for python (especially implementation-wise -- platform-independence screwed up is where it hurted me most :( )

Comment: this solution is sensitive to trailing os.sep. Say os.sep=='/'. dirname(foo/bar) -> foo, but dirname(foo/bar/) -> foo/bar

Comment: That's by design. It comes down to the interpretation of a path with a trailing /. Do you consider "path1" equals to "path1/"? The library use the most general interpretation that they are distinct. In some context people may want to treat them as equivalent. In this case you can do a rstrip('/') first. Had the library pick the other interpretation you will lost fidelity.

Comment: @WaiYipTung "Do you consider "path1" equals to "path1/"" --> Yes, because they **are**.  In what context would you ever _not_ treat them as equivalent?

Comment: @Ryan, I don't know about that. There is an entire RFC 1808 written to address the issue of relative path in URI and all the subtlety of the presence and absence of a trailing /. If you know of any documentation that says they should be treated equivalent in general please point it out.

Comment: @WaiYipTung Hmm, okay, seems silly but I thought this was just a library decision.  Makes more sense then.

Answer (score 163):

#### Using Pathlib (available since [python-3.4](/questions/tagged/python-3.4))

```python
from pathlib import Path
Path('C:\Program Files').parent
# Returns a Pathlib object
```

#### The traditional method

```python
import os.path
os.path.dirname('C:\Program Files')
# Returns a string
```

#### Which method should I use?

Use the traditional method if:

- You are worried about existing code generating errors if it were to use a Pathlib object. (Since Pathlib objects cannot be concatenated to strings. Pathlib objects can be concatenated to Pathlib objects, so if you are starting a new project and use Pathlib everywhere, you will be fine.)
- Your Python version is less than 3.4.
- You're putting together filepaths for uses outside of the current Python program (sending the path to other services running on the machine, storing the path in a database, etc.), and you haven't been given any Pathlib objects to start with. Say for example that you have a filepath, it is currently a string, and you want to get the parent directory so you can put it in some JSON. It would be kind of silly to convert to a Pathlib object and back again just for that.

If none of the above apply, use Pathlib.

---

#### What is Pathlib?

If you don't know what Pathlib is, the Pathlib module is a terrific module that makes working with files even easier for you. Most if not all of the built in Python modules that work with files will accept both Pathlib objects and strings. I've highlighted below a couple of examples from the [Pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) that showcase some of the neat things you can do with Pathlib.

Navigating inside a directory tree:

```python
>>> p = Path('/etc')
>>> q = p / 'init.d' / 'reboot'
>>> q
PosixPath('/etc/init.d/reboot')
>>> q.resolve()
PosixPath('/etc/rc.d/init.d/halt')
```

Querying path properties:

```python
>>> q.exists()
True
>>> q.is_dir()
False
```

Comment: This is the only sane answer. If you're forced to use Python 2, just `pip install pathlib2` and use the backport.

Comment: This solution is NOT sensitive to trailing `os.sep`!

Comment: You don't really have to "worry about existing code generating errors if it were to use a Pathlib object" because you can just wrap the pathlib object:  `path_as_string = str(Path(<somepath>))`.

Answer (score 50):

```
import os
p = os.path.abspath('..')
```

`C:\Program Files` ---> `C:\\\`

`C:\` ---> `C:\\\`

Comment: This only gets the parent of the CWD, not the parent of an arbitrary path as the OP asked.

Comment: Add the double dots at the end of your URL and it will work

E.g  
`os.path.abspath(r'E:\O3M_Tests_Embedded\branches\sw_test_level_gp\test_scripts\..\..')`

Result:
`E:\\O3M_Tests_Embedded\\branches`

Comment: This means: `/`.

Answer (score 36):

An alternate solution of @kender

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath(yourpath))
```

where `yourpath` is the path you want the parent for.

But this solution is not perfect, since it will not handle the case where `yourpath` is an empty string, or a dot.

This other solution will handle more nicely this corner case:

```
import os
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(yourpath, os.pardir))
```

Here the outputs for every case that can find (Input path is relative):

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('a/b/'))          => 'a'
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('a/b/', os.pardir))  => 'a'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('a/b'))           => 'a'
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('a/b', os.pardir))   => 'a'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('a/'))            => ''
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('a/', os.pardir))    => '.'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('a'))             => ''
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('a', os.pardir))     => '.'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('.'))             => ''
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('.', os.pardir))     => '..'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath(''))              => ''
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('', os.pardir))      => '..'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('..'))            => ''
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('..', os.pardir))    => '../..'
```

Input path is absolute (Linux path):

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('/a/b'))          => '/a'
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('/a/b', os.pardir))  => '/a'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('/a'))            => '/'
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('/a', os.pardir))    => '/'

os.path.dirname(os.path.normpath('/'))             => '/'
os.path.normpath(os.path.join('/', os.pardir))     => '/'
```

Comment: Normalizing the path is always a good practice, especially when doing cross-platform work.

Comment: @Maxim This solution was not perfect, I did improved it since the orginal solution does not handle one case

Answer (score 20):

```
os.path.split(os.path.abspath(mydir))[0]
```

Comment: This won't work for paths which are to a directory, it'll just return the directory again.

Comment: @AnthonyBriggs, I just tried this using Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and it seems to work fine. `os.path.split(os.path.abspath("this/is/a/dir/"))[0]` returns `'/home/daniel/this/is/a'` as expected.  I don't at the moment have a running Windows box to check there. On what setup have you observed the behavior that you report?

Comment: You could do `parentdir = os.path.split(os.path.apspath(dir[:-1]))[0]`. This - I am certain - works because if there is a slash on the end, then it is removed; if there is no slash, this will still work (even if the last part of the path is only one char long) because of the preceding slash. This of course assumes that the path is proper and not say something like `/a//b/c///d////` (in unix this is valid still), which in most cases they are (proper) especially when you do something like `os.path.abspath` or any other `os.path` function.

Comment: Also, to counteract a lot of slashes on the end, you could just write a small for loop that removes those. I'm sure there could even be a clever one-liner to do it, or maybe do that and os.path.split in one line.

Comment: @Den Menes I just saw you comment. It doesn't work if you have something like `os.path.split("a/b//c/d///")` and, for example, `cd //////dev////// is equivalent to `cd /dev/` or `cd /dev`; all of these are valid in linux. I just came up with this and it may be useful, though: `os.path.split(path[:tuple(ind for ind, char in enumerate(path) if char != "/" and char != "\\")[-1]])[0]`. (This essentially searches for the last non-slash, and gets the substring of the path up to that char.) I used `path = "/a//b///c///d////"` and then ran the aforementioned statement and got `'/a//b///c'`.

Comment: With the understanding that the line above is for demonstration, I'd still recommend to not use "dir" as a variable/reference. It is also a built-in function.

Answer (score 16):

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(somepath, '..'))
```

Observe:

```
import posixpath
import ntpath

print ntpath.abspath(ntpath.join('C:\\', '..'))
print ntpath.abspath(ntpath.join('C:\\foo', '..'))
print posixpath.abspath(posixpath.join('/', '..'))
print posixpath.abspath(posixpath.join('/home', '..'))
```

Comment: Does not work with Symbolic links

Answer (score 10):

```
import os
print"------------------------------------------------------------"
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print("example 1: "+SITE_ROOT)
PARENT_ROOT=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, os.pardir))
print("example 2: "+PARENT_ROOT)
GRANDPAPA_ROOT=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PARENT_ROOT, os.pardir))
print("example 3: "+GRANDPAPA_ROOT)
print "------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(<your_path>))
```

For example in Ubuntu:

```
>>> my_path = '/home/user/documents'
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(my_path))
# Output: 'user'
```

For example in Windows:

```
>>> my_path = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32'
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(my_path))
# Output: 'WINDOWS'
```

Both examples tried in Python 2.7

Answer (score 9):

Suppose we have directory structure like

1]

```
/home/User/P/Q/R
```

We want to access the path of "P" from the directory R then we can access using

```
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("..", os.pardir));
```

2]

```
/home/User/P/Q/R
```

We want to access the path of "Q" directory from the directory R then we can access using

```
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(".", os.pardir));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want *only* the ***name*** of the folder that is the immediate parent of the file provided as an argument and **not** the *absolute path* to that file:

`os.path.split(os.path.dirname(currentDir))[1]`

i.e. with a `currentDir` value of `/home/user/path/to/myfile/file.ext`

The above command will return:

`myfile`

Comment: os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(current_dir)) also works here.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os.path

os.path.abspath(os.pardir)
```

Comment: This presumes you want the parent directory of "the current working directory" and not the parent directory any path in general.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding something to the Tung's answer (you need to use `rstrip('/')` to be more of the safer side if you're on a unix box).

```
>>> input1 = "../data/replies/"
>>> os.path.dirname(input1.rstrip('/'))
'../data'
>>> input1 = "../data/replies"
>>> os.path.dirname(input1.rstrip('/'))
'../data'
```

But, if you don't use `rstrip('/')`, given your input is

```
>>> input1 = "../data/replies/"
```

would output,

```
>>> os.path.dirname(input1)
'../data/replies'
```

which is probably not what you're looking at as you want both `"../data/replies/"` and `"../data/replies"` to behave the same way.

Comment: I would recommend to not use "input" as a variable/reference. It is a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

```
print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.pardir))
```

You can use this to get the parent directory of the current location of your py file.

Comment: That suggestion often leads to bugs. os.getcwd() is often NOT where "your py file" is. Think packages. If I "import some_package_with_subpackages" many modules will not be in that package's top-most directory. os.getcwd() returns where you execute top-most script. And that also presumes you are doing it from a command line.

Comment: Like DevPlayer noted os.getcwd() is not necessarily the location of your python file. sys.argv[0] is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os 

def parent_directory():
  # Create a relative path to the parent of the current working directory 
  relative_parent = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "..") # .. means parent directory

  # Return the absolute path of the parent directory
  return os.path.abspath(relative_parent)

print(parent_directory())
```

Answer (score 0):

**GET Parent Directory Path** and **make New directory** (name `new_dir`)

#### Get Parent Directory Path

```
os.path.abspath('..')
os.pardir
```

#### Example 1

```
import os
print os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'new_dir'))
```

#### Example 2

```
import os
print os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.abspath('..'), 'new_dir'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.abspath('D:\Dir1\Dir2\..')

>>> 'D:\Dir1'
```

So a `..` helps

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def parent_filedir(n):
    return parent_filedir_iter(n, os.path.dirname(__file__))

def parent_filedir_iter(n, path):
    n = int(n)
    if n <= 1:
        return path
    return parent_filedir_iter(n - 1, os.path.dirname(path))

test_dir = os.path.abspath(parent_filedir(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given above are all perfectly fine for going up one or two directory levels, but they may get a bit cumbersome if one needs to traverse the directory tree by many levels (say, 5 or 10). This can be done concisely by joining a list of `N` `os.pardir`s in `os.path.join`. Example:

```
import os
# Create list of ".." times 5
upup = [os.pardir]*5
# Extract list as arguments of join()
go_upup = os.path.join(*upup)
# Get abspath for current file
up_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, go_upup))
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the parent of the current working directory:

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path().resolve().parent
```